# Fitting empirical distribution to theoretical ones with Scipy (Python)?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy, distribution

**INTRODUCTION**: I have a list of more than 30,000 integer values ranging from 0 to 47, inclusive, e.g.`[0,0,0,0,..,1,1,1,1,...,2,2,2,2,...,47,47,47,...]` sampled from some continuous distribution. The values in the list are not necessarily in order, but order doesn't matter for this problem.

**PROBLEM**: Based on my distribution I would like to calculate p-value (the probability of seeing greater values) for any given value. For example, as you can see p-value for 0 would be approaching 1 and p-value for higher numbers would be tending to 0.

I don't know if I am right, but to determine probabilities I think I need to fit my data to a theoretical distribution that is the most suitable to describe my data. I assume that some kind of goodness of fit test is needed to determine the best model.

Is there a way to implement such an analysis in Python (`Scipy` or `Numpy`)?
Could you present any examples?

Comment: You have only discrete empirical values but want a continuous distribution? Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: It seems nonsensical. What do the numbers represent? Measurements with limited precision?

Comment: Michael, I explained what the numbers represent in my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615489/fitting-distributions-goodness-of-fit-p-value-is-it-possible-to-do-this-with-s

Comment: That's count data. It's not a continuous distribution.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37559471/2087463) if you would like to see what all the distributions look like or for an idea of how to access all of them.

Comment: Check the accepted answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455018/how-to-identify-the-distribution-of-the-given-data-in-python

Answer (score 309):

## Distribution Fitting with Sum of Square Error (SSE)

This is an update and modification to [Saullo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16651955/2087463), that uses the full list of the current [`scipy.stats` distributions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) and returns the distribution with the least [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares) between the distribution's histogram and the data's histogram.

### Example Fitting

Using the [El Niño dataset from `statsmodels`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/datasets/generated/elnino.html#el-nino-sea-surface-temperatures), the distributions are fit and error is determined. The distribution with the least error is returned.

#### All Distributions

[image: All Fitted Distributions]

#### Best Fit Distribution

[image: Best Fit Distribution]

#### Example Code

```
%matplotlib inline

import warnings
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy.stats._continuous_distns import _distn_names
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16.0, 12.0)
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

# Create models from data
def best_fit_distribution(data, bins=200, ax=None):
    """Model data by finding best fit distribution to data"""
    # Get histogram of original data
    y, x = np.histogram(data, bins=bins, density=True)
    x = (x + np.roll(x, -1))[:-1] / 2.0

    # Best holders
    best_distributions = []

    # Estimate distribution parameters from data
    for ii, distribution in enumerate([d for d in _distn_names if not d in ['levy_stable', 'studentized_range']]):

        print("{:>3} / {:<3}: {}".format( ii+1, len(_distn_names), distribution ))

        distribution = getattr(st, distribution)

        # Try to fit the distribution
        try:
            # Ignore warnings from data that can't be fit
            with warnings.catch_warnings():
                warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
                
                # fit dist to data
                params = distribution.fit(data)

                # Separate parts of parameters
                arg = params[:-2]
                loc = params[-2]
                scale = params[-1]
                
                # Calculate fitted PDF and error with fit in distribution
                pdf = distribution.pdf(x, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg)
                sse = np.sum(np.power(y - pdf, 2.0))
                
                # if axis pass in add to plot
                try:
                    if ax:
                        pd.Series(pdf, x).plot(ax=ax)
                    end
                except Exception:
                    pass

                # identify if this distribution is better
                best_distributions.append((distribution, params, sse))
        
        except Exception:
            pass

    
    return sorted(best_distributions, key=lambda x:x[2])

def make_pdf(dist, params, size=10000):
    """Generate distributions's Probability Distribution Function """

    # Separate parts of parameters
    arg = params[:-2]
    loc = params[-2]
    scale = params[-1]

    # Get sane start and end points of distribution
    start = dist.ppf(0.01, *arg, loc=loc, scale=scale) if arg else dist.ppf(0.01, loc=loc, scale=scale)
    end = dist.ppf(0.99, *arg, loc=loc, scale=scale) if arg else dist.ppf(0.99, loc=loc, scale=scale)

    # Build PDF and turn into pandas Series
    x = np.linspace(start, end, size)
    y = dist.pdf(x, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg)
    pdf = pd.Series(y, x)

    return pdf

# Load data from statsmodels datasets
data = pd.Series(sm.datasets.elnino.load_pandas().data.set_index('YEAR').values.ravel())

# Plot for comparison
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = data.plot(kind='hist', bins=50, density=True, alpha=0.5, color=list(matplotlib.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'])[1]['color'])

# Save plot limits
dataYLim = ax.get_ylim()

# Find best fit distribution
best_distibutions = best_fit_distribution(data, 200, ax)
best_dist = best_distibutions[0]

# Update plots
ax.set_ylim(dataYLim)
ax.set_title(u'El Niño sea temp.\n All Fitted Distributions')
ax.set_xlabel(u'Temp (°C)')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')

# Make PDF with best params 
pdf = make_pdf(best_dist[0], best_dist[1])

# Display
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = pdf.plot(lw=2, label='PDF', legend=True)
data.plot(kind='hist', bins=50, density=True, alpha=0.5, label='Data', legend=True, ax=ax)

param_names = (best_dist[0].shapes + ', loc, scale').split(', ') if best_dist[0].shapes else ['loc', 'scale']
param_str = ', '.join(['{}={:0.2f}'.format(k,v) for k,v in zip(param_names, best_dist[1])])
dist_str = '{}({})'.format(best_dist[0].name, param_str)

ax.set_title(u'El Niño sea temp. with best fit distribution \n' + dist_str)
ax.set_xlabel(u'Temp. (°C)')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
```

Comment: Awesome. Consider using `density=True` instead of `normed=True` in `np.histogram()`. ^^

Comment: What version of pandas is required for the 'density' keyword? I get 'AttributeError: Unknown property density' from matplotlib with matplotlib 2.0.2 and pandas 0.20.2 when executing this code snippet because of 'data.plot(..., density=True, ...)'.

Comment: I do not remember what version I used to originally answer the question or what version contained @Peque's recommendation.  You can check for version issues/compatibility in pandas/matplotlib docs.  There should be docs for each version.  If you want, you can use `normed=True` instead.

Comment: @tmthydvnprt I think you changed `normed` to `density` in `np.histogram()` (which was my recommendation as [the former is deprecated](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)), but you also changed it in the `.plot()` methods (I think Matplotlib's `pyplot.hist()` uses `normed` and never supported `density`). ;-)

Comment: @tmthydvnprt Maybe you could undo the changes in the `.plot()` methods to avoid future confusion. ^^

Comment: To get distribution names: `from scipy.stats._continuous_distns import _distn_names`.  You can then use something like `getattr(scipy.stats, distname)` for each `distname` in _distn_names`.  Useful because the distributions are updated with different SciPy versions.

Comment: That's a good method, but it's not working correctly. Please, consider this CSV file as an input for the Series: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kOa35v0NHjWHK8VmMDY-sKiGZyeJzw6z

Comment: Can you please explain why this code checks for best fit of continuous distributions only, and cannot check for discrete or multivariate distributions. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe? Can you explain a specific case?

Comment: Hi @tmthydvnprt Yes. Suppose I have a dataset that has a binomial distribution and another one that is a poisson. When I add scipy.stats.binom or scipy.stats.poisson to your example code, they are not generated on the plot. The example code (which I'm still trying to comprehend) doesn't check for discrete distributions (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html). Is there a way for me to check for best fit of discrete distributions?

Comment: Very cool. I had to update the color parameter - `ax = data.plot(kind='hist', bins=50, normed=True, alpha=0.5, 
               color=list(matplotlib.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'])[1]['color'])`

Comment: @tmthydvnprt Sir, why do you do this trick with the `roll()` a the start?

Comment: I do not understand why do you put this line: x = (x + np.roll(x, -1))[:-1] / 2.0. Can you explain me the objective of this operation, please?

Comment: Hey! I don't know if it's too late, but I'm struggling to generate random numbers with the best fit found by this code. I know I should use the `rvs()` method, but I'm not sure what input is needed for the `c` argument. Any ideas?

Comment: @JuanC you could do `from scipy.stats import beta` `beta.rvs(a=1.74, b=2.69, loc=18.91, scale=10.62)`. Optionally, you can include the `size` parameter for how many samples you want to generate. [Docs here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html)

Comment: @tmthydvnprt Hello, would you please re write the code to the newest version of python libs?  or at least mention the best version of matplotlib to use this code? there are error with the new library. regards.

Comment: @jartymcfly not sure if you worked out why `np.roll()` was used? It's just a moving average with a window size of `2.0`. `x` in this case, represents the `bin_edges`, so performing this calculation returns the centre of each bin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not sure I understand how to calculate the probability of a number from the pdf. For example, what is the probability to get two? I think this code creates CDF from this PDF: `pdf.cumsum() / pdf.sum()` and then, I can calculate `cdf(2+epsilon)-cdf(2)`. What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, is there a specific reason why discrete distributions are not checked?  I know we can model a discrete data with a continuous distribution, but it is not optimal.

Comment: I had to add at the end plt.show() to see the results.

Comment: just in case someone in 2020 is wondering how to make this run, change `import statsmodel as sm` to `import statsmodel.api as sm`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is this suitable for continuous variables  if the Distributions list replaced by continuous distributions by obtaining the names of the continuous distributions as @BradSolomon suggested in his comment?

Comment: A supplement to Rafael's comment: the package name is `statsmodels`, not `statsmodel`

Comment: @RafaelSilva et at.: If the code is not working anymore and you have a fix, please update the answer instead of adding a comment. I now incorporated all the changes that have been mentioned here to get it to run again.

Comment: wth is that end there? lol

Comment: Here are 2  distributions (as of such plot) - the aim is to reveal features, causing the distinguishes between 2 peaks. OR perhaps, you lack data to fill this gap for the possibility to do the statistical inference - increase your sample-size...

Answer (score 191):

There are [more than 90 implemented distribution functions in SciPy v1.6.0](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#continuous-distributions). You can test how some of them fit to your data using their [`fit()` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit). Check the code below for more details:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.stats
size = 30000
x = np.arange(size)
y = scipy.int_(np.round_(scipy.stats.vonmises.rvs(5,size=size)*47))
h = plt.hist(y, bins=range(48))

dist_names = ['gamma', 'beta', 'rayleigh', 'norm', 'pareto']

for dist_name in dist_names:
    dist = getattr(scipy.stats, dist_name)
    params = dist.fit(y)
    arg = params[:-2]
    loc = params[-2]
    scale = params[-1]
    if arg:
        pdf_fitted = dist.pdf(x, *arg, loc=loc, scale=scale) * size
    else:
        pdf_fitted = dist.pdf(x, loc=loc, scale=scale) * size
    plt.plot(pdf_fitted, label=dist_name)
    plt.xlim(0,47)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

References:

- [Fitting distributions, goodness of fit, p-value. Is it possible to do this with Scipy (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16651524/832621)
- [Distribution fitting with Scipy](http://glowingpython.blogspot.de/2012/07/distribution-fitting-with-scipy.html)

And here a list with the names of all distribution functions available in Scipy 0.12.0 (VI):

```
dist_names = [ 'alpha', 'anglit', 'arcsine', 'beta', 'betaprime', 'bradford', 'burr', 'cauchy', 'chi', 'chi2', 'cosine', 'dgamma', 'dweibull', 'erlang', 'expon', 'exponweib', 'exponpow', 'f', 'fatiguelife', 'fisk', 'foldcauchy', 'foldnorm', 'frechet_r', 'frechet_l', 'genlogistic', 'genpareto', 'genexpon', 'genextreme', 'gausshyper', 'gamma', 'gengamma', 'genhalflogistic', 'gilbrat', 'gompertz', 'gumbel_r', 'gumbel_l', 'halfcauchy', 'halflogistic', 'halfnorm', 'hypsecant', 'invgamma', 'invgauss', 'invweibull', 'johnsonsb', 'johnsonsu', 'ksone', 'kstwobign', 'laplace', 'logistic', 'loggamma', 'loglaplace', 'lognorm', 'lomax', 'maxwell', 'mielke', 'nakagami', 'ncx2', 'ncf', 'nct', 'norm', 'pareto', 'pearson3', 'powerlaw', 'powerlognorm', 'powernorm', 'rdist', 'reciprocal', 'rayleigh', 'rice', 'recipinvgauss', 'semicircular', 't', 'triang', 'truncexpon', 'truncnorm', 'tukeylambda', 'uniform', 'vonmises', 'wald', 'weibull_min', 'weibull_max', 'wrapcauchy']
```

Comment: What if `normed = True` in plotting the histogram? You wouldn't multiply `pdf_fitted` by the `size`, right?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37559471/2087463) if you would like to see what all the distributions look like or for an idea of how to access all of them.

Comment: @SaulloCastro What does the 3 values in param represent, in the output of dist.fit

Comment: @shaifaliGupta actually the number of outputs of dist.fit depend on the statistical distribution chosen, and for all distributions the  two last parameters are loc and scale.

Comment: To get distribution names: `from scipy.stats._continuous_distns import _distn_names`.  You can then use something like `getattr(scipy.stats, distname)` for each `distname` in _distn_names`.  Useful because the distributions are updated with different SciPy versions.

Comment: There is one thing missing, which is answered by @tmthydvnprt , the values are not labelled correctly so you need the make_pdf function posted by tmthydvnprt below here. Thanks for this amazing comment though!

Comment: Okay, but how do you know which distribution to choose? You're just forcing the data into each distribution.

Comment: @NoName to find the goodness of fitting you can use the [follow up answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37616966/832621)

Comment: once you have found the best fit..how do you sample from that?

Comment: @Luigi87 just use the `rvs()` function of each distribution, here in the code represented as the `dist` object

Comment: many thanks. In the documentation it says "The shape parameter(s) for the distribution", does it also work if the distribution is multivariate? many thanks

Comment: @Luigi87 I think yes

Comment: Thank you for showing the dist.pdf with conditional use of *arg, this was also useful for generalizing stats.probplot and passing entire param tup: `stats.probplot(x, sparams=param, dist=dist, plot=ax)`

Answer (score 20):

You can try the [distfit library](https://erdogant.github.io/distfit). In case you have more questions, let me know, I am also the developer of this open-source library.

```
pip install distfit

# Create 1000 random integers, value between [0-50]
X = np.random.randint(0, 50,1000)

# Retrieve P-value for y
y = [0,10,45,55,100]

# From the distfit library import the class distfit
from distfit import distfit

# Initialize.
# Set any properties here, such as alpha.
# The smoothing can be of use when working with integers. Otherwise your histogram
# may be jumping up-and-down, and getting the correct fit may be harder.
dist = distfit(alpha=0.05, smooth=10)

# Search for best theoretical fit on your empirical data
dist.fit_transform(X)

> [distfit] >fit..
> [distfit] >transform..
> [distfit] >[norm      ] [RSS: 0.0037894] [loc=23.535 scale=14.450] 
> [distfit] >[expon     ] [RSS: 0.0055534] [loc=0.000 scale=23.535] 
> [distfit] >[pareto    ] [RSS: 0.0056828] [loc=-384473077.778 scale=384473077.778] 
> [distfit] >[dweibull  ] [RSS: 0.0038202] [loc=24.535 scale=13.936] 
> [distfit] >[t         ] [RSS: 0.0037896] [loc=23.535 scale=14.450] 
> [distfit] >[genextreme] [RSS: 0.0036185] [loc=18.890 scale=14.506] 
> [distfit] >[gamma     ] [RSS: 0.0037600] [loc=-175.505 scale=1.044] 
> [distfit] >[lognorm   ] [RSS: 0.0642364] [loc=-0.000 scale=1.802] 
> [distfit] >[beta      ] [RSS: 0.0021885] [loc=-3.981 scale=52.981] 
> [distfit] >[uniform   ] [RSS: 0.0012349] [loc=0.000 scale=49.000] 

# Best fitted model
best_distr = dist.model
print(best_distr)

# Uniform shows best fit, with 95% CII (confidence intervals), and all other parameters
> {'distr': <scipy.stats._continuous_distns.uniform_gen at 0x16de3a53160>,
>  'params': (0.0, 49.0),
>  'name': 'uniform',
>  'RSS': 0.0012349021241149533,
>  'loc': 0.0,
>  'scale': 49.0,
>  'arg': (),
>  'CII_min_alpha': 2.45,
>  'CII_max_alpha': 46.55}

# Ranking distributions
dist.summary

# Plot the summary of fitted distributions
dist.plot_summary()
```

[image]

```
# Make prediction on new datapoints based on the fit
dist.predict(y)

# Retrieve your pvalues with 
dist.y_pred
# array(['down', 'none', 'none', 'up', 'up'], dtype='<U4')
dist.y_proba
array([0.02040816, 0.02040816, 0.02040816, 0.        , 0.        ])

# Or in one dataframe
dist.df

# The plot function will now also include the predictions of y
dist.plot()
```

[image: Best fit]

Note that in this case, all points will be significant because of the uniform distribution. You can filter with the dist.y_pred if required.

More detailed information and examples can be found at the [documentation pages](https://erdogant.github.io/distfit).

Comment: are you the author?

Comment: True, I added this in the response for clarity.

Comment: This helps me a lot! I tried this to do a first glance of my data distribution then I use a MLE approach to confirm. BTW, Do you have plans to release an extension with MLE approach?

Comment: Can you share your approach? Perhaps we can discuss this further over here: https://github.com/erdogant/distfit/issues

Answer (score 19):

`fit()` method mentioned by @Saullo Castro provides maximum likelihood estimates (MLE).  The best distribution for your data is the one give you the highest can be determined by several different ways: such as

1, the one that gives you the highest log likelihood.

2, the one that gives you the smallest AIC, BIC or BICc values (see wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion, basically can be viewed as log likelihood adjusted for number of parameters, as distribution with more parameters are expected to fit better)

3, the one that maximize the Bayesian posterior probability. (see wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability)

Of course, if you already have a distribution that should describe you data (based on the theories in your particular field) and want to stick to that, you will skip the step of identifying the best fit distribution.

`scipy` does not come with a function to calculate log likelihood (although MLE method is provided), but hard code one is easy: see [Is the build-in probability density functions of `scipy.stat.distributions` slower than a user provided one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431629/is-the-build-in-probability-density-functions-of-scipy-stat-distributions-slow)

Comment: How would I apply this method to a situation where the data has already been binned - that is is already a histogram rather than generating a histogram from the data?

Comment: @pete, that would be a situation of interval-censored data, there are maximum likelihood method for it, but it is currently not implemented in `scipy`

Comment: Don't forget the Evidence

Answer (score 8):

AFAICU, your distribution is discrete (and nothing but discrete). Therefore just counting the frequencies of different values and normalizing them should be enough for your purposes. So, an example to demonstrate this:

```
In []: values= [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
In []: counts= asarray(bincount(values), dtype= float)
In []: cdf= counts.cumsum()/ counts.sum()
```

Thus, probability of seeing values higher than `1` is simply (according to the [complementary cumulative distribution function (ccdf)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Complementary_cumulative_distribution_function_.28tail_distribution.29):

```
In []: 1- cdf[1]
Out[]: 0.40000000000000002
```

Please note that [ccdf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Complementary_cumulative_distribution_function_.28tail_distribution.29) is closely related to [survival function (sf)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function), but it's also defined with discrete distributions, whereas [sf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function) is defined only for contiguous distributions.

Answer (score 7):

The following code is the version of the general answer but with corrections and clarity.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import random

mpl.style.use("ggplot")

def danoes_formula(data):
    """
    DANOE'S FORMULA
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Doane's_formula
    """
    N = len(data)
    skewness = st.skew(data)
    sigma_g1 = math.sqrt((6*(N-2))/((N+1)*(N+3)))
    num_bins = 1 + math.log(N,2) + math.log(1+abs(skewness)/sigma_g1,2)
    num_bins = round(num_bins)
    return num_bins

def plot_histogram(data, results, n):
    ## n first distribution of the ranking
    N_DISTRIBUTIONS = {k: results[k] for k in list(results)[:n]}

    ## Histogram of data
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
    plt.hist(data, density=True, ec='white', color=(63/235, 149/235, 170/235))
    plt.title('HISTOGRAM')
    plt.xlabel('Values')
    plt.ylabel('Frequencies')

    ## Plot n distributions
    for distribution, result in N_DISTRIBUTIONS.items():
        # print(i, distribution)
        sse = result[0]
        arg = result[1]
        loc = result[2]
        scale = result[3]
        x_plot = np.linspace(min(data), max(data), 1000)
        y_plot = distribution.pdf(x_plot, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg)
        plt.plot(x_plot, y_plot, label=str(distribution)[32:-34] + ": " + str(sse)[0:6], color=(random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)))
    
    plt.legend(title='DISTRIBUTIONS', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
    plt.show()

def fit_data(data):
    ## st.frechet_r,st.frechet_l: are disbled in current SciPy version
    ## st.levy_stable: a lot of time of estimation parameters
    ALL_DISTRIBUTIONS = [        
        st.alpha,st.anglit,st.arcsine,st.beta,st.betaprime,st.bradford,st.burr,st.cauchy,st.chi,st.chi2,st.cosine,
        st.dgamma,st.dweibull,st.erlang,st.expon,st.exponnorm,st.exponweib,st.exponpow,st.f,st.fatiguelife,st.fisk,
        st.foldcauchy,st.foldnorm, st.genlogistic,st.genpareto,st.gennorm,st.genexpon,
        st.genextreme,st.gausshyper,st.gamma,st.gengamma,st.genhalflogistic,st.gilbrat,st.gompertz,st.gumbel_r,
        st.gumbel_l,st.halfcauchy,st.halflogistic,st.halfnorm,st.halfgennorm,st.hypsecant,st.invgamma,st.invgauss,
        st.invweibull,st.johnsonsb,st.johnsonsu,st.ksone,st.kstwobign,st.laplace,st.levy,st.levy_l,
        st.logistic,st.loggamma,st.loglaplace,st.lognorm,st.lomax,st.maxwell,st.mielke,st.nakagami,st.ncx2,st.ncf,
        st.nct,st.norm,st.pareto,st.pearson3,st.powerlaw,st.powerlognorm,st.powernorm,st.rdist,st.reciprocal,
        st.rayleigh,st.rice,st.recipinvgauss,st.semicircular,st.t,st.triang,st.truncexpon,st.truncnorm,st.tukeylambda,
        st.uniform,st.vonmises,st.vonmises_line,st.wald,st.weibull_min,st.weibull_max,st.wrapcauchy
    ]
    
    MY_DISTRIBUTIONS = [st.beta, st.expon, st.norm, st.uniform, st.johnsonsb, st.gennorm, st.gausshyper]

    ## Calculae Histogram
    num_bins = danoes_formula(data)
    frequencies, bin_edges = np.histogram(data, num_bins, density=True)
    central_values = [(bin_edges[i] + bin_edges[i+1])/2 for i in range(len(bin_edges)-1)]

    results = {}
    for distribution in MY_DISTRIBUTIONS:
        ## Get parameters of distribution
        params = distribution.fit(data)
        
        ## Separate parts of parameters
        arg = params[:-2]
        loc = params[-2]
        scale = params[-1]
    
        ## Calculate fitted PDF and error with fit in distribution
        pdf_values = [distribution.pdf(c, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg) for c in central_values]
        
        ## Calculate SSE (sum of squared estimate of errors)
        sse = np.sum(np.power(frequencies - pdf_values, 2.0))
        
        ## Build results and sort by sse
        results[distribution] = [sse, arg, loc, scale]
        
    results = {k: results[k] for k in sorted(results, key=results.get)}
    return results
        
def main():
    ## Import data
    data = pd.Series(sm.datasets.elnino.load_pandas().data.set_index('YEAR').values.ravel())
    results = fit_data(data)
    plot_histogram(data, results, 5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

If you want to do a more detailed analysis, I recommend [Phittter library](https://pypi.org/project/phitter/)

```py
import phitter

data: list[int | float] = [...]

phitter_cont = phitter.PHITTER(
    data=data,
    fit_type="continuous",
    num_bins=15,
    confidence_level=0.95,
    minimum_sse=1e-2,
    distributions_to_fit=["beta", "normal", "fatigue_life", "triangular"],
)
phitter_cont.fit(n_workers=6)
```

Answer (score 6):

While many of the above answers are completely valid, no one seems to answer your question completely, specifically the part:

> I don't know if I am right, but to determine probabilities I think I need to fit my data to a theoretical distribution that is the most suitable to describe my data. I assume that some kind of goodness of fit test is needed to determine the best model.

### The parametric approach

This is the process you're describing of using some theoretical distribution and fitting the parameters to your data and there's some excellent answers how to do this.

### The non-parametric approach

However, it's also possible to use a non-parametric approach to your problem, which means you do not assume any underlying distribution at all.

By using the so-called Empirical distribution function which equals:
*Fn(x)= SUM( I[X<=x] ) / n*. So the proportion of values below x.

As was pointed out in one of the above answers is that what you're interested in is the inverse CDF (cumulative distribution function), which is equal to *1-F(x)*

It can be shown that the empirical distribution function will converge to whatever 'true' CDF that generated your data.

Furthermore, it is straightforward to construct a 1-alpha confidence interval by:

```
L(X) = max{Fn(x)-en, 0}
U(X) = min{Fn(x)+en, 0}
en = sqrt( (1/2n)*log(2/alpha)
```

Then *P( L(X) <= F(X) <= U(X) ) >= 1-alpha* for all x.

I'm quite surprised that [PierrOz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/83125/pierroz) answer has 0 votes, while it's a completely valid answer to the question using a non-parametric approach to estimating F(x).

Note that the issue you mention of P(X>=x)=0 for any x>47 is simply a personal preference that might lead you to chose the parametric approach above the non-parametric approach. Both approaches however are completely valid solutions to your problem.

For more details and proofs of the above statements I would recommend having a look at
'All of Statistics: A Concise Course in Statistical Inference by Larry A. Wasserman'. An excellent book on both parametric and non-parametric inference.

**EDIT:**
Since you specifically asked for some python examples it can be done using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

def empirical_cdf(data, x):
    return np.sum(x<=data)/len(data)

def p_value(data, x):
    return 1-empirical_cdf(data, x)

# Generate some data for demonstration purposes
data = np.floor(np.random.uniform(low=0, high=48, size=30000))

print(empirical_cdf(data, 20))
print(p_value(data, 20)) # This is the value you're interested in
```

Comment: Isn't the python code the opposite of Fn(x)= SUM( I[X<=x] ) / n?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I found was by using fitter module and you can simply `pip install fitter`.
All you got to do is import the dataset by pandas.
It has built-in function to search all 80 distributions from scipy  and get the best fit to the data by various methods. Example:

```
f = Fitter(height, distributions=['gamma','lognorm', "beta","burr","norm"])
f.fit()
f.summary()
```

Here the author has provided a list of distributions since scanning all 80 can be time consuming.

```
f.get_best(method = 'sumsquare_error')
```

This will get you 5 best distributions with their fit criteria:

```
            sumsquare_error    aic          bic       kl_div
chi2             0.000010  1716.234916 -1945.821606     inf
gamma            0.000010  1716.234909 -1945.821606     inf
rayleigh         0.000010  1711.807360 -1945.526026     inf
norm             0.000011  1758.797036 -1934.865211     inf
cauchy           0.000011  1762.735606 -1934.803414     inf
```

You also have `distributions=get_common_distributions()` attribute which has about 10 most commonly used distributions, and fits and checks them for you.

It also has a bunch of other functions like plotting histograms and all and complete documentation can be found [here](https://fitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

It is a seriously underrated module for scientists, engineers, and in general.

Answer (score 4):

What about storing your data in a dictionary where keys would be the numbers between 0 and 47 and values the number of occurrences of their related keys in your original list?

Thus your likelihood p(x) will be the sum of all the values for keys greater than x divided by 30000.

Comment: In this case the p(x) will be the same (equals 0) for any value greater than 47. I need a continuous probability distribution.

Comment: @s_sherly - It would be probably a good thing if you could edit and clarify your question better, as indeed the *"the probability of seeing greater values"* - as you put it - **IS** zero for values that are above the highest value in the pool.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like probability density estimation problem to me.

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
occurences = [0,0,0,0,..,1,1,1,1,...,2,2,2,2,...,47]
values = range(0,48)
kde = gaussian_kde(map(float, occurences))
p = kde(values)
p = p/sum(p)
print "P(x>=1) = %f" % sum(p[1:])
```

Also see http://jpktd.blogspot.com/2009/03/using-gaussian-kernel-density.html.

Comment: For future readers: this solution (or at least the idea) provides the simplest answer to the OPs questions ('what is the p-value') - it would be interesting to know how this compares to some of the more involved methods that fit a known distribution.

Comment: Do Gaussian kernel regressions work for all distributions?

Comment: @mikey As a general rule, no regressions work for all distributions. They're not bad though

Answer (score 3):

With [OpenTURNS](http://www.openturns.org/), I would use the BIC criteria to select the best distribution that fits such data. This is because this criteria does not give too much advantage to the distributions which have more parameters. Indeed, if a distribution has more parameters, it is easier for the fitted distribution to be closer to the data. Moreover, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov may not make sense in this case, because a small error in the measured values will have a huge impact on the p-value.

To illustrate the process, I load the El-Nino data, which contains 732 monthly temperature measurements from 1950 to 2010:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
dta = sm.datasets.elnino.load_pandas().data
dta['YEAR'] = dta.YEAR.astype(int).astype(str)
dta = dta.set_index('YEAR').T.unstack()
data = dta.values
```

It is easy to get the 30 of built-in univariate factories of distributions with the `GetContinuousUniVariateFactories` static method. Once done, the `BestModelBIC` static method returns the best model and the corresponding BIC score.

```
sample = ot.Sample([[p] for p in data]) # data reshaping
tested_factories = ot.DistributionFactory.GetContinuousUniVariateFactories()
best_model, best_bic = ot.FittingTest.BestModelBIC(sample,
                                                   tested_factories)
print("Best=",best_model)
```

which prints:

```
Best= Beta(alpha = 1.64258, beta = 2.4348, a = 18.936, b = 29.254)
```

In order to graphically compare the fit to the histogram, I use the `drawPDF` methods of the best distribution.

```
import openturns.viewer as otv
graph = ot.HistogramFactory().build(sample).drawPDF()
bestPDF = best_model.drawPDF()
bestPDF.setColors(["blue"])
graph.add(bestPDF)
graph.setTitle("Best BIC fit")
name = best_model.getImplementation().getClassName()
graph.setLegends(["Histogram",name])
graph.setXTitle("Temperature (°C)")
otv.View(graph)
```

This produces:

[image: Beta fit to the El-Nino temperatures]

More details on this topic are presented in the [BestModelBIC](http://openturns.github.io/openturns/latest/user_manual/_generated/openturns.FittingTest_BestModelBIC.html) doc. It would be possible to include the Scipy distribution in the [SciPyDistribution](http://openturns.github.io/openturns/latest/user_manual/_generated/openturns.SciPyDistribution.html) or even with ChaosPy distributions with [ChaosPyDistribution](http://openturns.github.io/openturns/latest/user_manual/_generated/openturns.ChaospyDistribution.html), but I guess that the current script fulfills most practical purposes.

Comment: You should probably declare an interest?

Answer (score 0):

I redesign the distribution function from first answer where I included a selection parameter for selecting one of Goodness-to-fit tests which will narrow down the distribution function which fits the data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab

def make_hist(data):
    #### General code:
    bins_formulas = ['auto', 'fd', 'scott', 'rice', 'sturges', 'doane', 'sqrt']
    bins = np.histogram_bin_edges(a=data, bins='fd', range=(min(data), max(data)))
    # print('Bin value = ', bins)

    # Obtaining the histogram of data:
    Hist, bin_edges = histogram(a=data, bins=bins, range=(min(data), max(data)), density=True)
    bin_mid = (bin_edges + np.roll(bin_edges, -1))[:-1] / 2.0  # go from bin edges to bin middles
    return Hist, bin_mid

def make_pdf(dist, params, size):
    """Generate distributions's Probability Distribution Function """

    # Separate parts of parameters
    arg = params[:-2]
    loc = params[-2]
    scale = params[-1]

    # Get sane start and end points of distribution
    start = dist.ppf(0.01, *arg, loc=loc, scale=scale) if arg else dist.ppf(0.01, loc=loc, scale=scale)
    end = dist.ppf(0.99, *arg, loc=loc, scale=scale) if arg else dist.ppf(0.99, loc=loc, scale=scale)

    # Build PDF and turn into pandas Series
    x = np.linspace(start, end, size)
    y = dist.pdf(x, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg)
    pdf = pd.Series(y, x)
    return pdf, x, y

def compute_r2_test(y_true, y_predicted):
    sse = sum((y_true - y_predicted)**2)
    tse = (len(y_true) - 1) * np.var(y_true, ddof=1)
    r2_score = 1 - (sse / tse)
    return r2_score, sse, tse

def get_best_distribution_2(data, method, plot=False):
    dist_names = ['alpha', 'anglit', 'arcsine', 'beta', 'betaprime', 'bradford', 'burr', 'cauchy', 'chi', 'chi2', 'cosine', 'dgamma', 'dweibull', 'erlang', 'expon', 'exponweib', 'exponpow', 'f', 'fatiguelife', 'fisk', 'foldcauchy', 'foldnorm', 'frechet_r', 'frechet_l', 'genlogistic', 'genpareto', 'genexpon', 'genextreme', 'gausshyper', 'gamma', 'gengamma', 'genhalflogistic', 'gilbrat',  'gompertz', 'gumbel_r', 'gumbel_l', 'halfcauchy', 'halflogistic', 'halfnorm', 'hypsecant', 'invgamma', 'invgauss', 'invweibull', 'johnsonsb', 'johnsonsu', 'ksone', 'kstwobign', 'laplace', 'logistic', 'loggamma', 'loglaplace', 'lognorm', 'lomax', 'maxwell', 'mielke', 'moyal', 'nakagami', 'ncx2', 'ncf', 'nct', 'norm', 'pareto', 'pearson3', 'powerlaw', 'powerlognorm', 'powernorm', 'rdist', 'reciprocal', 'rayleigh', 'rice', 'recipinvgauss', 'semicircular', 't', 'triang', 'truncexpon', 'truncnorm', 'tukeylambda', 'uniform', 'vonmises', 'wald', 'weibull_min', 'weibull_max', 'wrapcauchy']
    
    # Applying the Goodness-to-fit tests to select the best distribution that fits the data:
    dist_results = []
    dist_IC_results = []
    params = {}
    params_IC = {}
    params_SSE = {}

    if method == 'sse':
########################################################################################################################
######################################## Sum of Square Error (SSE) test ################################################
########################################################################################################################
        # Best holders
        best_distribution = st.norm
        best_params = (0.0, 1.0)
        best_sse = np.inf

        for dist_name in dist_names:
            dist = getattr(st, dist_name)
            param = dist.fit(data)
            params[dist_name] = param
            N_len = len(list(data))
            # Obtaining the histogram:
            Hist_data, bin_data = make_hist(data=data)

            # fit dist to data
            params_dist = dist.fit(data)

            # Separate parts of parameters
            arg = params_dist[:-2]
            loc = params_dist[-2]
            scale = params_dist[-1]

            # Calculate fitted PDF and error with fit in distribution
            pdf = dist.pdf(bin_data, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg)
            sse = np.sum(np.power(Hist_data - pdf, 2.0))

            # identify if this distribution is better
            if best_sse > sse > 0:
                best_distribution = dist
                best_params = params_dist
                best_stat_test_val = sse

        print('\n################################ Sum of Square Error test parameters #####################################')
        best_dist = best_distribution
        print("Best fitting distribution (SSE test) :" + str(best_dist))
        print("Best SSE value (SSE test) :" + str(best_stat_test_val))
        print("Parameters for the best fit (SSE test) :" + str(params[best_dist]))
        print('###########################################################################################################\n')

########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################

    if method == 'r2':
########################################################################################################################
##################################################### R Square (R^2) test ##############################################
########################################################################################################################
    # Best holders
    best_distribution = st.norm
    best_params = (0.0, 1.0)
    best_r2 = np.inf

    for dist_name in dist_names:
        dist = getattr(st, dist_name)
        param = dist.fit(data)
        params[dist_name] = param
        N_len = len(list(data))
        # Obtaining the histogram:
        Hist_data, bin_data = make_hist(data=data)

        # fit dist to data
        params_dist = dist.fit(data)

        # Separate parts of parameters
        arg = params_dist[:-2]
        loc = params_dist[-2]
        scale = params_dist[-1]

        # Calculate fitted PDF and error with fit in distribution
        pdf = dist.pdf(bin_data, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg)
        r2 = compute_r2_test(y_true=Hist_data, y_predicted=pdf)

        # identify if this distribution is better
        if best_r2 > r2 > 0:
            best_distribution = dist
            best_params = params_dist
            best_stat_test_val = r2

    print('\n############################## R Square test parameters ###########################################')
    best_dist = best_distribution
    print("Best fitting distribution (R^2 test) :" + str(best_dist))
    print("Best R^2 value (R^2 test) :" + str(best_stat_test_val))
    print("Parameters for the best fit (R^2 test) :" + str(params[best_dist]))
    print('#####################################################################################################\n')

########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################

    if method == 'ic':
########################################################################################################################
######################################## Information Criteria (IC) test ################################################
########################################################################################################################
        for dist_name in dist_names:
            dist = getattr(st, dist_name)
            param = dist.fit(data)
            params[dist_name] = param
            N_len = len(list(data))

            # Obtaining the histogram:
            Hist_data, bin_data = make_hist(data=data)

            # fit dist to data
            params_dist = dist.fit(data)

            # Separate parts of parameters
            arg = params_dist[:-2]
            loc = params_dist[-2]
            scale = params_dist[-1]

            # Calculate fitted PDF and error with fit in distribution
            pdf = dist.pdf(bin_data, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg)
            sse = np.sum(np.power(Hist_data - pdf, 2.0))

            # Obtaining the log of the pdf:
            loglik = np.sum(dist.logpdf(bin_data, *params_dist))
            k = len(params_dist[:])
            n = len(data)
            aic = 2 * k - 2 * loglik
            bic = n * np.log(sse / n) + k * np.log(n)
            dist_IC_results.append((dist_name, aic))
            # dist_IC_results.append((dist_name, bic))

        # select the best fitted distribution and store the name of the best fit and its IC value
        best_dist, best_ic = (min(dist_IC_results, key=lambda item: item[1]))

        print('\n############################ Information Criteria (IC) test parameters ##################################')
        print("Best fitting distribution (IC test) :" + str(best_dist))
        print("Best IC value (IC test) :" + str(best_ic))
        print("Parameters for the best fit (IC test) :" + str(params[best_dist]))
        print('###########################################################################################################\n')

########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################

    if method == 'chi':
########################################################################################################################
################################################ Chi-Square (Chi^2) test ###############################################
########################################################################################################################
        # Set up 50 bins for chi-square test
        # Observed data will be approximately evenly distrubuted aross all bins
        percentile_bins = np.linspace(0,100,51)
        percentile_cutoffs = np.percentile(data, percentile_bins)
        observed_frequency, bins = (np.histogram(data, bins=percentile_cutoffs))
        cum_observed_frequency = np.cumsum(observed_frequency)

        chi_square = []
        for dist_name in dist_names:
            dist = getattr(st, dist_name)
            param = dist.fit(data)
            params[dist_name] = param

            # Obtaining the histogram:
            Hist_data, bin_data = make_hist(data=data)

            # fit dist to data
            params_dist = dist.fit(data)

            # Separate parts of parameters
            arg = params_dist[:-2]
            loc = params_dist[-2]
            scale = params_dist[-1]

            # Calculate fitted PDF and error with fit in distribution
            pdf = dist.pdf(bin_data, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg)

            # Get expected counts in percentile bins
            # This is based on a 'cumulative distrubution function' (cdf)
            cdf_fitted = dist.cdf(percentile_cutoffs, *arg, loc=loc, scale=scale)
            expected_frequency = []
            for bin in range(len(percentile_bins) - 1):
                expected_cdf_area = cdf_fitted[bin + 1] - cdf_fitted[bin]
                expected_frequency.append(expected_cdf_area)

            # calculate chi-squared
            expected_frequency = np.array(expected_frequency) * size
            cum_expected_frequency = np.cumsum(expected_frequency)
            ss = sum(((cum_expected_frequency - cum_observed_frequency) ** 2) / cum_observed_frequency)
            chi_square.append(ss)

            # Applying the Chi-Square test:
            # D, p = scipy.stats.chisquare(f_obs=pdf, f_exp=Hist_data)
            # print("Chi-Square test Statistics value for " + dist_name + " = " + str(D))
            print("p value for " + dist_name + " = " + str(chi_square))
            dist_results.append((dist_name, chi_square))

        # select the best fitted distribution and store the name of the best fit and its p value
        best_dist, best_stat_test_val = (min(dist_results, key=lambda item: item[1]))

        print('\n#################################### Chi-Square test parameters #######################################')
        print("Best fitting distribution (Chi^2 test) :" + str(best_dist))
        print("Best p value (Chi^2 test) :" + str(best_stat_test_val))
        print("Parameters for the best fit (Chi^2 test) :" + str(params[best_dist]))
        print('#########################################################################################################\n')

########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################

    if method == 'ks':
########################################################################################################################
########################################## Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) test ################################################
########################################################################################################################
        for dist_name in dist_names:
            dist = getattr(st, dist_name)
            param = dist.fit(data)
            params[dist_name] = param

            # Applying the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test:
            D, p = st.kstest(data, dist_name, args=param)
            # D, p = st.kstest(data, dist_name, args=param, N=N_len, alternative='greater')
            # print("Kolmogorov-Smirnov test Statistics value for " + dist_name + " = " + str(D))
            print("p value for " + dist_name + " = " + str(p))
            dist_results.append((dist_name, p))

        # select the best fitted distribution and store the name of the best fit and its p value
        best_dist, best_stat_test_val = (max(dist_results, key=lambda item: item[1]))

        print('\n################################ Kolmogorov-Smirnov test parameters #####################################')
        print("Best fitting distribution (KS test) :" + str(best_dist))
        print("Best p value (KS test) :" + str(best_stat_test_val))
        print("Parameters for the best fit (KS test) :" + str(params[best_dist]))
        print('###########################################################################################################\n')

########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################

    # Collate results and sort by goodness of fit (best at top)
    results = pd.DataFrame()
    results['Distribution'] = dist_names
    results['chi_square'] = chi_square
    # results['p_value'] = p_values
    results.sort_values(['chi_square'], inplace=True)

    # Plotting the distribution with histogram:
    if plot:
        bins_val = np.histogram_bin_edges(a=data, bins='fd', range=(min(data), max(data)))
        plt.hist(x=data, bins=bins_val, range=(min(data), max(data)), density=True)
        # pylab.hist(x=data, bins=bins_val, range=(min(data), max(data)))
        best_param = params[best_dist]
        best_dist_p = getattr(st, best_dist)
        pdf, x_axis_pdf, y_axis_pdf = make_pdf(dist=best_dist_p, params=best_param, size=len(data))
        plt.plot(x_axis_pdf, y_axis_pdf, color='red', label='Best dist ={0}'.format(best_dist))
        plt.legend()
        plt.title('Histogram and Distribution plot of data')
        # plt.show()
        plt.show(block=False)
        plt.pause(5)  # Pauses the program for 5 seconds
        plt.close('all')

    return best_dist, best_stat_test_val, params[best_dist]
```

then continue to make_pdf function to get the selected distribution based on the your Goodness-of-fit test/s.

Comment: can you explain what are each column in the pdf variable?

Comment: @El_que_no_duda Can you specify exact area of my answer?

Comment: # Calculate fitted PDF and error with fit in distribution
        pdf = dist.pdf(bin_data, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg)

Comment: @El_que_no_duda the bin_data variable gets the bar histogram data and from there it is used as input to obtain the pdf.

Comment: Sure, but what is the meaning of each column?

Comment: @El_que_no_duda okay, for each column I used different types of Goodness-of-fit tests where you specify the which fitting method you want and it will fit the distribution based on histogram data and calculate p value of fitting method you chose in order to display it in the dataframe and arrange distribution that mostly fits your dataset

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Timothy Davenports answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37616966/1497139) i have refactored the code to be useable as a library and made it available as a github and pypi project see:

- https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyProbabilityDistributionFit
- https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyProbabilityDistributionFit/blob/main/pdffit/distfit.py

One goal is to make the density option available and to output the result as files. See the main part of the implementation:

```py
    bfd=BestFitDistribution(data)
    for density in [True,False]:
        suffix="density" if density else ""
        bfd.analyze(title=u'El Niño sea temp.',x_label=u'Temp (°C)',y_label='Frequency',outputFilePrefix=f"/tmp/ElNinoPDF{suffix}",density=density)
    # uncomment for interactive display
    # plt.show()
```

[image: all]
[image: best fit]

There is are also a unit tests for the library see e.g.
[Normal distribution test](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyProbabilityDistributionFit/issues/3)

```py
def testNormal(self):
        '''
        test the normal distribution
        '''
        # use euler constant as seed
        np.random.seed(0)
        # statistically relevant number of datapoints
        datapoints=1000
        a = np.random.normal(40, 10, datapoints)
        df= pd.DataFrame({'nums':a})
        outputFilePrefix="/tmp/normalDist"
        bfd=BestFitDistribution(df,debug=True)
        bfd.analyze(title="normal distribution",x_label="x",y_label="random",outputFilePrefix=outputFilePrefix)
```

[image: normal all]
[image: normal best fit]
Please [add issues to the project](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pyProbabilityDistributionFit/issues/new) if you see problems or room for improvement. Discussions is also enabled.

the code below might not be up-todate please use pypi or the github repository for the most current version.

```py
'''
Created on 2022-05-17

see 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python/37616966#37616966

@author: https://stackoverflow.com/users/832621/saullo-g-p-castro
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37616966/1497139

@author: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2087463/tmthydvnprt
see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37616966/1497139

@author: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1497139/wolfgang-fahl
see 

'''
import traceback
import sys
import warnings

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st

from scipy.stats._continuous_distns import _distn_names

import statsmodels.api as sm

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class BestFitDistribution():
    '''
    Find the best Probability Distribution Function for the given data
    '''
    
    def __init__(self,data,distributionNames:list=None,debug:bool=False):
        '''
        constructor
        
        Args:
            data(dataFrame): the data to analyze
            distributionNames(list): list of distributionNames to try
            debug(bool): if True show debugging information
        '''
        self.debug=debug
        self.matplotLibParams()
        if distributionNames is None:
            self.distributionNames=[d for d in _distn_names if not d in ['levy_stable', 'studentized_range']]
        else:
            self.distributionNames=distributionNames
        self.data=data
        
    def matplotLibParams(self):
        '''
        set matplotlib parameters
        '''
        matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16.0, 12.0)
        #matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
        matplotlib.use("WebAgg")

    # Create models from data
    def best_fit_distribution(self,bins:int=200, ax=None,density:bool=True):
        """
        Model data by finding best fit distribution to data
        """
        # Get histogram of original data
        y, x = np.histogram(self.data, bins=bins, density=density)
        x = (x + np.roll(x, -1))[:-1] / 2.0
    
        # Best holders
        best_distributions = []
        distributionCount=len(self.distributionNames)
        # Estimate distribution parameters from data
        for ii, distributionName in enumerate(self.distributionNames):
    
            print(f"{ii+1:>3} / {distributionCount:<3}: {distributionName}")
    
            distribution = getattr(st, distributionName)
    
            # Try to fit the distribution
            try:
                # Ignore warnings from data that can't be fit
                with warnings.catch_warnings():
                    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
                    
                    # fit dist to data
                    params = distribution.fit(self.data)
    
                    # Separate parts of parameters
                    arg = params[:-2]
                    loc = params[-2]
                    scale = params[-1]
                    
                    # Calculate fitted PDF and error with fit in distribution
                    pdf = distribution.pdf(x, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg)
                    sse = np.sum(np.power(y - pdf, 2.0))
                    
                    # if axis pass in add to plot
                    try:
                        if ax:
                            pd.Series(pdf, x).plot(ax=ax)
                    except Exception:
                        pass
    
                    # identify if this distribution is better
                    best_distributions.append((distribution, params, sse))
            
            except Exception as ex:
                if self.debug:
                    trace=traceback.format_exc()
                    msg=f"fit for {distributionName} failed:{ex}\n{trace}"
                    print(msg,file=sys.stderr)
                pass
        
        return sorted(best_distributions, key=lambda x:x[2])

    def make_pdf(self,dist, params:list, size=10000):
        """
        Generate distributions's Probability Distribution Function 
        
        Args:
            dist: Distribution
            params(list): parameter
            size(int): size
            
        Returns:
            dataframe: Power Distribution Function 
        
        """
    
        # Separate parts of parameters
        arg = params[:-2]
        loc = params[-2]
        scale = params[-1]
    
        # Get sane start and end points of distribution
        start = dist.ppf(0.01, *arg, loc=loc, scale=scale) if arg else dist.ppf(0.01, loc=loc, scale=scale)
        end   = dist.ppf(0.99, *arg, loc=loc, scale=scale) if arg else dist.ppf(0.99, loc=loc, scale=scale)
    
        # Build PDF and turn into pandas Series
        x = np.linspace(start, end, size)
        y = dist.pdf(x, loc=loc, scale=scale, *arg)
        pdf = pd.Series(y, x)
    
        return pdf
    
    def analyze(self,title,x_label,y_label,outputFilePrefix=None,imageFormat:str='png',allBins:int=50,distBins:int=200,density:bool=True):
        """
        
        analyze the Probabilty Distribution Function
        
        Args:
            data: Panda Dataframe or numpy array
            title(str): the title to use
            x_label(str): the label for the x-axis
            y_label(str): the label for the y-axis
            outputFilePrefix(str): the prefix of the outputFile
            imageFormat(str): imageFormat e.g. png,svg
            allBins(int): the number of bins for all
            distBins(int): the number of bins for the distribution
            density(bool): if True show relative density
        """
        self.allBins=allBins
        self.distBins=distBins
        self.density=density
        self.title=title
        self.x_label=x_label
        self.y_label=y_label
        self.imageFormat=imageFormat
        self.outputFilePrefix=outputFilePrefix
        self.color=list(matplotlib.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'])[1]['color']
        self.best_dist=None
        self.analyzeAll()
        if outputFilePrefix is not None:
            self.saveFig(f"{outputFilePrefix}All.{imageFormat}", imageFormat)
            plt.close(self.figAll)
        if self.best_dist:
            self.analyzeBest()
            if outputFilePrefix is not None:
                self.saveFig(f"{outputFilePrefix}Best.{imageFormat}", imageFormat)
                plt.close(self.figBest)
            
    def analyzeAll(self):
        '''
        analyze the given data
        
        '''
        # Plot for comparison
        figTitle=f"{self.title}\n All Fitted Distributions"
        self.figAll=plt.figure(figTitle,figsize=(12,8))
        ax = self.data.plot(kind='hist', bins=self.allBins, density=self.density, alpha=0.5, color=self.color)
        
        # Save plot limits
        dataYLim = ax.get_ylim()
        # Update plots
        ax.set_ylim(dataYLim)
        ax.set_title(figTitle)
        ax.set_xlabel(self.x_label)
        ax.set_ylabel(self.y_label)
        
        # Find best fit distribution
        best_distributions = self.best_fit_distribution(bins=self.distBins, ax=ax,density=self.density)
        if len(best_distributions)>0:
            self.best_dist = best_distributions[0]
            # Make PDF with best params 
            self.pdf = self.make_pdf(self.best_dist[0], self.best_dist[1])
        
    def analyzeBest(self):
        '''
        analyze the Best Property Distribution function
        '''
        # Display
        figLabel="PDF"
        self.figBest=plt.figure(figLabel,figsize=(12,8))
        ax = self.pdf.plot(lw=2, label=figLabel, legend=True)
        self.data.plot(kind='hist', bins=self.allBins, density=self.density, alpha=0.5, label='Data', legend=True, ax=ax,color=self.color)
        
        param_names = (self.best_dist[0].shapes + ', loc, scale').split(', ') if self.best_dist[0].shapes else ['loc', 'scale']
        param_str = ', '.join(['{}={:0.2f}'.format(k,v) for k,v in zip(param_names, self.best_dist[1])])
        dist_str = '{}({})'.format(self.best_dist[0].name, param_str)
        
        ax.set_title(f'{self.title} with best fit distribution \n' + dist_str)
        ax.set_xlabel(self.x_label)
        ax.set_ylabel(self.y_label)

    def saveFig(self,outputFile:str=None,imageFormat='png'):
        '''
        save the current Figure to the given outputFile
        
        Args:
            outputFile(str): the outputFile to save to
            imageFormat(str): the imageFormat to use e.g. png/svg
        '''
        plt.savefig(outputFile, format=imageFormat) # dpi 
     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Load data from statsmodels datasets
    data = pd.Series(sm.datasets.elnino.load_pandas().data.set_index('YEAR').values.ravel())
    
    bfd=BestFitDistribution(data)
    for density in [True,False]:
        suffix="density" if density else ""
        bfd.analyze(title=u'El Niño sea temp.',x_label=u'Temp (°C)',y_label='Frequency',outputFilePrefix=f"/tmp/ElNinoPDF{suffix}",density=density)
    # uncomment for interactive display
    # plt.show()
```