# How to speed up Poisson pmf function?

Tags: python, scipy, distribution

My use case is to evaluate Poisson pmf on all points which is less than say, 10, and I would call such function multiple of times with difference lambdas. The lambdas are not known ahead of time so I cannot vectorize lambdas.

I heard from somewhere about a secret trick which is to use `_pmf`. What is the downside to do so? But still, it is a bit slow, is there any way to improve it without rewriting the pmf in C from scratch?

```
%timeit scipy.stats.poisson.pmf(np.arange(0,10),3.3)
%timeit scipy.stats.poisson._pmf(np.arange(0,10),3.3)
a = np.arange(0,10)
%timeit scipy.stats.poisson._pmf(a,3.3)

10000 loops, best of 3: 94.5 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.2 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.7 µs per loop
```

#### Update

Ok, simply I was just too lazy to write in cython. I had expected there is a faster solution for all discrete distribution that can be evaluated sequentially (iteratively) for consecutive `x`. E.g. `P(X=3) = P(X=2) * lambda / 3 if X ~ Pois(lambda)`

Related: [Is the build-in probability density functions of `scipy.stat.distributions` slower than a user provided one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431629/is-the-build-in-probability-density-functions-of-scipy-stat-distributions-slow)

I have less faith in Scipy and Python now. The library function isn't as advanced as what I had expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of `scipy.stats` distributions support vectorized evaluation:

```
>>> poisson.pmf(1, [5, 6, 7, 8])
array([ 0.03368973,  0.01487251,  0.00638317,  0.0026837 ])
```

This may or may not be fast enough, but you can try taking `pmf` calls out of the loop.

Re difference between `pmf` and `_pmf`: the real work is done in the underscored functions (`_pmf`, `_cdf` etc) while the public functions (`pmf`, `cdf`) make sure that only valid arguments make it to the `_pmf` (The output of `_pmf` is not guaranteed to be meaningful if the arguments are invalid, so use on your own risk).

```
>>> poisson.pmf(1, -1)
nan
>>> poisson._pmf(1, -1)
/home/br/virtualenvs/scipy-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_discrete_distns.py:432: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  Pk = k*log(mu)-gamln(k+1) - mu
nan
```

Further details: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py#L2721

Answer (score 2):

1. Try implementing the pmf in cython. If your scipy is part of a package like Anaconda or Enthought you probably have cython installed. http://cython.org/
2. Try running it with pypy. http://pypy.org/
3. Rent time on a big AWS server (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `scipy.stats.poisson` class is tragically slow compared to just a simple python implementation.

No cython or vectors or anything.

```py
import math


def poisson_pmf(x, mu):
    return mu**x / math.factorial(x) * math.exp(-mu)


def poisson_cdf(k, mu):
    p_total = 0.0
    for x in range(k + 1):
        p_total += poisson_pmf(x, mu)
    return p_total
```

And if you check the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/c2fa6570360674246030feae1ad9c299c2c70902/scipy/stats/_discrete_distns.py#L766) of `scipy.stats.poisson` (even the underscore prefixed versions) then it is clear why!

The above implementation is now **ONLY 10x slower** than the exact equivalent in C (compiled with `gcc -O3` v9.3). The scipy version is at least **another 10x slower**.

```c
#include <math.h>

unsigned long factorial(unsigned n) {
  unsigned long fact = 1;
  for (unsigned k = 2; k <= n; ++k)
    fact *= k;
  return fact;
}

double poisson_pmf(unsigned x, double mu) {
  return pow(mu, x) / factorial(x) * exp(-mu);
}

double poisson_cdf(unsigned k, double mu) {
  double p_total = 0.0;
  for (unsigned x = 0; x <= k; ++x)
    p_total += poisson_pmf(x, mu);
  return p_total;
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution is only faster for reasonably small x. When I try this with `x = 10000`, `mu = 10`, poisson_pmf takes 2.7 ms, and a frozen scipy.stats.poisson object's pmf takes 97 _µs_.