# Fitting either Guassian or Gamma distribution to data in Python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian, gamma

I have some measured data which can be either a well established gaussian or something that seems to be a gamma distribution, I currently have the following code (snippet) which performs quite well for data that is nicely gaussian:

```
def gaussFunction(x, A, mu, sigma):
    return A*numpy.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2.*sigma**2))

# Snippet of the code that does the fitting
p0 = [numpy.max(y_points), x_points[numpy.argmax(y_points)],0.1]
# Attempt to fit a gaussian function to the calibrant space
try:
  coeff, var_matrix = curve_fit(self.gaussFunction, x_points, y_points, p0)
  newX = numpy.linspace(x_points[0],x_points[-1],1000)
  newY = self.gaussFunction(newX, *coeff)
  fig =  plt.figure()
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
  plt.plot(x_points, y_points, 'b*')
  plt.plot(newX,newY, '--')
  plt.show()
```

Demonstration that it works well for datapoints which are nicely gaussian:

[image]

The problem however arises that some of my datapoints are not matching with a good gaussian and I get this:

[image]

I would be tempted to try a [cubic spline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html) but conceptually I would like to stick to a Gaussian curve fit since that is the data structure that should be within the data (which can occur with a knee or a tail in some data as shown in the second figure). I would highly appreciate if someone has any tip or suggestion on how to deal with this 'issue'.

Comment: maybe [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16651955/832621) will help you to use `scipy` built-in statistical functions to fit your data...

Comment: Are your data bound to be >0? Might try truncated Gaussian. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution

Comment: The data is always above 0, I have to admit that I just went for a cubic spline for now but I might revisit this problem at a later point.

Comment: Could you provide x_points and y_points, please?!