# How to calculate the entropy of a gamma distribution using scipy(python)?

Tags: python, scipy, entropy, gamma-distribution

I tried the [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python) by Saullo Castro to get the parameters of a gamma distribution, using scipy.

```
import scipy
import scipy.stats

size = 30000
x = scipy.arange(size)
y = scipy.int_(scipy.round_(scipy.stats.vonmises.rvs(5,size=size)*47))
dist = getattr(scipy.stats, 'gamma')
param = dist.fit(y)
dist.entropy(param)
```

gives me the entropy result, which does not make sense. Where am I wrong here?

```
array([ 5.54183717,         nan, -0.56062118])
```

In scipy documentation, it states that

```
entropy(a, loc=0, scale=1)  (Differential) entropy of the RV.
```

where

```
a is the array of parameters of the gamma distribution
```

Comment: Can you provide the link to the documentation where you found: `a is the array of parameters of the gamma distribution`.
[scipy.stats.rv_continuous.entropy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.entropy.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.entropy) suggests, that it should be `dist.entropy(*param)` instead.

Comment: @cel Thank you very much for your help =) I forgot to add *
    
    a is the array of parameters of the gamma distribution

is my own interpretation