# How to estimate density function and calculate its peaks?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have started to use python for analysis. I would like to do the following:

1. Get the distribution of dataset
2. Get the peaks in this distribution

I used gaussian_kde from scipy.stats to make estimation for kernel density function. Does guassian_kde make any assumption about the data ?. I am using data that are changed over time. so if data has one distribution (e.g. Gaussian), it could have another distribution later. Does gaussian_kde have any drawbacks in this scenario?. It was suggested in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python) to try to fit the data in every distribution in order to get the data distribution. So what's the difference between using gaussian_kde and the answer provided in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python). I used the code below, I was wondering also to know is gaussian_kde good way to estimate pdf if the data will be changed over time ?. I know one advantage of gaussian_kde is that it calculate bandwidth automatically by a rule of thumb as in [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html). Also, how can I get its peaks?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import scipy.stats
df = pd.read_csv('D:\dataset.csv')
pdf = scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde(df)
x = np.linspace((df.min()-1),(df.max()+1), len(df)) 
y = pdf(x)                          

pl.plot(x, y, color = 'r') 
pl.hist(data_column, normed= True)
pl.show(block=True)
```

Comment: The first few sentences are very hard to understand. You may want to be more explicit there. In what way do you think `gaussian kde` normalizes your data? And why would that lead to just one peak? Also I don't get the sentence after that.

Comment: Accept my apology, I rephrased the question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you need to distinguish non-parametric density (the one implemented in `scipy.stats.kde`) from parametric density (the one in the [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python) you mention). To illustrate the difference between these two, try the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
gaussian1 = -6 + 3 * np.random.randn(1700)
gaussian2 = 4 + 1.5 * np.random.randn(300)
gaussian_mixture = np.hstack([gaussian1, gaussian2])

df = pd.DataFrame(gaussian_mixture, columns=['data'])

# non-parametric pdf
nparam_density = stats.kde.gaussian_kde(df.values.ravel())
x = np.linspace(-20, 10, 200)
nparam_density = nparam_density(x)

# parametric fit: assume normal distribution
loc_param, scale_param = stats.norm.fit(df)
param_density = stats.norm.pdf(x, loc=loc_param, scale=scale_param)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.hist(df.values, bins=30, normed=True)
ax.plot(x, nparam_density, 'r-', label='non-parametric density (smoothed by Gaussian kernel)')
ax.plot(x, param_density, 'k--', label='parametric density')
ax.set_ylim([0, 0.15])
ax.legend(loc='best')
```

[image]

From the graph, we see that the non-parametric density is nothing but a smoothed version of histogram. In histogram, for a particular observation `x=x0`, we use a bar to represent it (put all probability mass on that single point `x=x0` and zero elsewhere) whereas in non-parametric density estimation, we use a bell-shaped curve (the gaussian kernel) to represent that point (spreads over its neighbourhood). And the result is a smoothed density curve. This internal gaussian kernel has nothing to do with your distributional assumption on the underlying data `x`. Its sole purpose is for smoothing.

To get the mode of non-parametric density, we need to do an exhaustive search, as the density is not guaranteed to have uni-mode. As shown in the example above, if you quasi-Newton optimization algo starts between [5,10], it is very likely to end up with a local optimal point rather than the global one.

```
# get mode: exhastive search
x[np.argsort(nparam_density)[-1]]
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `x[nparam_density.argmax()]`. In addition, seems that `normed=True` is now deprecated, but one can use `density=True`.