# Determine outlier from non normal distribution vector

Tags: python, list, outliers

I would like to be able to determine outliers from a list where data don't follow a normal distribution.

```
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, ..., 2, 50, 100, 101, 102, 103, 101, ... 100, 150]

outlier = [50, 150]
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to fit the probability density function (pdf) to your data (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31253371/2402281)). And then you may take a look at how likely certain values are given your estimated function. Any data points that deviate too much from your pdf may be considered outliers.

---

**EDIT** Also given your data, it looks like you could fit your data with two normal distributions as [explained in this article](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/453794) with `µ1 = 2`, `µ2 = 102` and `σ1 = σ2 = 3` roughly. I'd suggest however to estimate these values empirically (or given that you know each Gaussian, just take the values from there). Finally, you might check if your pdf is indeed [multimodal iff `d > 1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution#Tests_for_unimodality).

---

Does that help you? In case it does not, please let us/me know why!

Cheers

Comment: thanks for the accurate and quick answer! I think indeed have the elements of answer to solve my problem;)

Comment: Hey @TheHadrien ! Glad my answer was helpful to you. Could you please still select it as helpful? Thank you!