# Mismatch between Scipy stat (KS-test) distribution and histogram plot of the data set

Tags: statistics, data-science, distribution, scipy.stats

I have a dataset like this

```
y = array([ 25.,  20.,  10.,  31.,  30.,  66.,  13.,   5.,   9.,   2.,   4.,
     9.,   6.,  26.,  72.,   7.,   5.,  18.,   8.,  12.,   4.,   7.,
   114.,   5.,   6.,  17.,  39.,   4.,   5.,  42.,  63.,   3.,   6.,
    16.,  17.,   4.,  27.,  18.,   3.,   7.,  48.,  24.,  72.,  21.,
    12.,  13., 106., 120.,   5.,  34.,  52.,  22.,   2.,   8.,   9.,
     5.,  35.,   4.,   4.,   1.,  56.,   1.,  17.,  34.,   3.,   5.,
    17.,  17.,  10.,  48.,   9., 195.,  20.,  60.,   5.,  77., 114.,
    59.,   1.,   1.,   1.,  67.,   9.,   4.,   1.,  13.,   6.,  46.,
    40.,   8.,   6.,   1.,   2.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   7.,   6.,  53.,
     6.,   3.,   4.,   2.,   1.,   1.,   5.,   1.,   5.,   1.,   7.,
     1.,   1.])
```

The corresponding histogram from this data is following

```
number_of_bins = len(y)
bin_cutoffs = np.linspace(np.percentile(y,0), np.percentile(y,99),number_of_bins)
h = plt.hist(y, bins = bin_cutoffs, color='red')
```

[image]

I test the dataset to get the actual parameter from scipy stat KS test with the following code (got this from [How to find probability distribution and parameters for real data? (Python 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487830/how-to-find-probability-distribution-and-parameters-for-real-data-python-3))

```
def get_best_distribution(data):
dist_names = ["norm", "exponweib", "weibull_max", "weibull_min","expon","pareto", "genextreme","gamma","beta"]
dist_results = []
params = {}
for dist_name in dist_names:
    dist = getattr(st, dist_name)
    param = dist.fit(data)

    params[dist_name] = param
    # Applying the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
    D, p = st.kstest(data, dist_name, args=param)
    print("p value for "+dist_name+" = "+str(p))
    dist_results.append((dist_name, p))

# select the best fitted distribution
best_dist, best_p = (max(dist_results, key=lambda item: item[1]))
# store the name of the best fit and its p value

print("Best fitting distribution: "+str(best_dist))
print("Best p value: "+ str(best_p))
print("Parameters for the best fit: "+ str(params[best_dist]))
return best_dist, best_p, params[best_dist]
```

The result shows that its genextreme distribution. The result is as shown bellow:

```
('genextreme',
0.1823402997669471,
(-1.119997717132149, 5.036499415233003, 6.2122664378291175))
```

The fitted curve using these attributes is following
[image]

From my understanding, the histogram suggests that it is a exponential distribution.But from KS test it shows another.Can anyone explain why this is happening or anything wrong?

Comment: What is killing exponential, I would venture, are several outliers at y>=100. Basically, huge CDF discrepancy for K-S at those value. Generalized extreme value distribution, I would guess, has a bit tempered PDF decrease at large y