# Generate random sample for exponentiated Weibull distribution using Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, probability-distribution, weibull

For a distribution for running [this scipy function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51742444/1176573) to detect the best fit as Exponentiated Weibull distribution and the function outputs 4 parameter values. But how to generate a sample `list` of data of size `n` that honours this kind of distribution.

I don't want to re-write function. Any python package which does this, would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you will use a `ppf` to generate from a rando seed.

For a simple completely fake example, let's say we fit a uniform random variable (with values from 0 to 15) to a Weibull distribution. Then, create a seed random variable (from 0 to 1 because it's the value of the quantiles that you will get) and put it in the `ppf` function.

```py
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np
# fitting part
samples = np.random.rand(10000)*15
dist = st.exponweib.fit(samples)
# generation part
sample_seed = np.random.rand(10000)
random_exponweib_samples = st.exponweib.ppf(sample_seed, *dist)
# plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(samples, label="uniform", alpha=.5)
plt.hist(random_exponweib_samples, label="exponweib", alpha=.5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

You'll have something like the following.
[image]

Please be careful and check for the documentation of the `ppf` concerning the weibull distrubiton. In my function `st.exponweib.ppf(sample_seed, *dist)` I just use `*dist` but it might be the case that the parameters should be sent differently, you can see it with the form of the orange plot which might not be correct.

Comment: Ok, Thanks it worked. For fitting part, data was read from a `pandas` `dataframe` and converted to `numpy` `array`. Also, later it was realised there were couple of errorneous data which falsely detected the distribution as `exponweib`. But actually a `normal` distribution after removing wrong data.