# Find best fit common probability density function, if already have a probability density function (Python's Fitter does not suffice)

Tags: numpy, distribution, data-fitting, probability-distribution

There are questions about finding best-fit p.d.f.s given some data: [How to find probability distribution and parameters for real data? (Python 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487830/how-to-find-probability-distribution-and-parameters-for-real-data-python-3), https://medium.com/the-researchers-guide/finding-the-best-distribution-that-fits-your-data-using-pythons-fitter-library-319a5a0972e9.

But I already have a p.d.f.

```
for i in range(N-100,len(normalized_p),10):
       plt.plot(x[i], normalized_p[i], label=f'n={i+1}', marker='o')
```

[image: probability density function]

and I want to find the best fit model.

To use the Fitter library mentioned above, I ended up just sampling data from my p.d.f.

```
data = np.random.choice(x[N-1], 100000, p=p[N-1]/sump[N-1])

f = Fitter(data,
           distributions=['gamma',
                          'lognorm',
                          "beta",
                          "burr"])
f.fit()
f.summary()
```

This barely works; because of the fact that I only sample discrete numbers, things can be slightly "out of alignment" with the bins, leading to weird spikes
[image: discrete data don't align with bins]
One solution is to add a little noise to the data so this minute misalignments don't impact the histogram as much.

**Is there any better way for me to do this task?**

Comment: If you already have the PDF then why are you trying to fit it?

Comment: @jared I would like to see if it matches any common distribution. It popped out of some number theoretic data I collected, but I don't recognize the shape (e.g. it sure as hell isn't a normal distribution)

Comment: Please consider providing the PDF and executable code that demonstrates the problem. I don't understand why you are only sampling "discrete numbers" (not integers, apparently?) from a probability *density* function, which would allow for sampling continuous numbers, or why the alignment to bins of a histogram affects fitting, given that many methods for fitting continuous distribution families to data do not involve histograms. Do you mean you have a normalized *histogram*, not the PDF as a continuous function? Or the PDF is a step function?

Comment: @MattHaberland So for each n, I have a sequence (of integers) in the variable k, denoted P(n,k). Let P(n) = sum_k P(n,k), so that fixing n, f_n(k) := P(n,k)/P(n) is now a probability density function on the integers k (k=1..n). I have normalized this function f_n(k) to a function g_n(x), which is supported on a discrete set (a rescaled copy of the integers k=1..n). I observe that these g_n(x) seem to approach a limiting curve (the p.d.f. of perhaps a common distribution), and I want to find what the limiting curve is. The issue is that the Fitter requires data, so I sample from g_n(x).

Comment: It looks like `Fitter` simply calls the `fit` method of SciPy distributions. `fit`uses maximum likelihood estimation to perform the fit, which does not see the spikes you see in the histogram; they are just a problem with the visualization. If you are happy with the way the fit is being performed and just don't like the visualization, I can suggest a workaround.

Comment: Another thought, though, is that you don't need to sample at random; it seems that `p[N-1]` represents an integer number of occurrences of each element in `x[N-1]`. You can generate that ideal sample like `np.repeat(x[N-1], p[N-1])`. This won't solve the visualization problem; it just eliminates some unnecessary stochasticity.

Comment: @MattHaberland that's funny; when there are weird spikes, the fit is visibly worse. It is only through tuning the number of bins (via `bins=...` inside the call to Fitter), or adding the noise (or both), that the curve actually does match closely. What was your suggestion for the visualization?

Comment: I was going to suggest plotting the histogram and PDF yourself, but I see now that Fitter does accept `bins` and passes it to NumPy, so just pass an appropriate sequence as`bins` to ensure that there is one abscissa in each bin (or the same number of abscissae per bin). See the documentation of `histogram` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) for defining bin edges.