# Scipy.stats's fit and pdf functions

Tags: python, scipy

I want to know how `scipy.stats` uses its methods `fit` and `pdf`. According to the documentation, `fit(data, a, loc = 0, scale = 1)` estimates parameters for `data` while `pdf(x, a, loc=0, scale=1) computes probability density function` . But I couldn't find how `fit` and `pdf` are actually performed, statistically and mathematically.

I am using the `sm.datasets.elnino` data, using the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python) from tmthydvnprt

```
import warnings
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
import statsmodels as sm
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.Series(sm.datasets.elnino.load_pandas().data.set_index('YEAR').values.ravel())


y, x = np.histogram(data, bins = 50, density = True)
x = (x + np.roll(x, -1))[:-1] / 2.0
distribution = st.gennorm

params = distribution.fit(data)
arg = params[:-2]
loc = params[-2]
scale = params[-1]
pdf = distribution.pdf(x, loc = loc, scale = scale, *arg)
sse = np.sum(np.power(y - pdf, 2.0))
```

Using `data`, `arg` = 4.3836, `loc` = 23.2991, `scale` = 3.8499.

**I want to know what `arg`, `loc`, and `scale` represent and how they are calculated.**

Thank you.

Comment: Your code is not complete (e.g. you don't show how `y` is created), so I don't think anyone can answer your last question.  It would be easier for someone to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ... and you checked the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#shifting-and-scaling), didn't you?