# How to find the probability density function's curve that best fit my distribution with python

Tags: python, statistics, distribution

I have sorted data with pandas so that I have this dataframe (I work with anaconda, jupyter notebook):

[image: dataframe]

I showed a histogram with the abscissa indexing "écart G-D" and ordinate "probabilité".

[image: histogram]

I found a topic on stack overflow that deals exactly what I want to do except that it is 7 years old and the code is obsolete! I still tried while correcting some things but it does not work (besides I do not even understand the code) ... 
Here is the link of the topic:
[Fitting empirical distribution to theoretical ones with Scipy (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python?lq=1)

I would like to graphically test the probability density function that best follows the shape of my histogram.
If anyone could enlighten me, it would be great because I'm really in a bind ...

Thank you.

Comment: The question is quite vague. One pdf that would fit your data exactly is $f(-13) = 0.004975$, $f(-12) = 0.00995$, ...

You need to at least first specify a family of distribution that you would be interested in fitting.

Comment: I would verify with exponantial law, Poisson's law and others laws, my goal is to find which law follows my data... I don't know if it is clear...

Comment: Do you specifically exclude data at point 0? Or maybe it is an artifact of data processing that there is a point at -1, at +1, but not at 0? It makes your histogram plot wrong

Comment: yes you are right, I this problem and I have changed the histogram plot, adding on the the abscissa 0 7 and 11 (the image of these numbers is 0)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [distfit](https://erdogant.github.io/distfit/pages/html/Performance.html) library in Python. It will determine the best theoretical distribution for your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can fit your data manually by calculating the parameters of a distribution(mean, lambda, etc) and use scipy to generate that distribution. Also, if your main objective is just fit the data to a distribution and then use that distribution later, you can use another software (Stat::Fit) to best fit to your data automatically and plot it on the histogram.

Comment: But just by analyzing the histogram it looks like a log-normal distribution, check its parameters and try it out.