# Is there a Python function to create points patterns?

Tags: python, r, pattern-matching

I have the following series data. It has 600 data points shown below and i want to generate an array of 100000 elements following the same pattern of the data using Python and i don't know how to do it. Could someone help me to do that?

I tried to plot the histogram and fit the data with some distribution but didn't work so well, because i think my data don't follow any distribution

```py
tup = levy.fit_levy(data)
array = tup[0].get('0')
random = levy_stable.rvs(array[0], array[1],array[2],array[3],size=100000)
```

Here is the the plot and the histogram of the data i'm trying to fit

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzEG2.png)

[Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIeIP.png)

Comment: maybe it needs `Regresion` in `Machine Learning` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do a kernel Smoothing to your data?

I had a list `x = [f1, f2,...,f600]` looking as yours

[image]

Using the KernelSmoothing method of [OpenTURNS](http://openturns.org) it was easy to fit a non-parametric distribution:

```
import openturns as ot
# format x as a sample of 600 points
sample = ot.Sample([[p] for p in x]) 
model = ot.KernelSmoothing().build(sample)
```

That's it!

[image]

Should you want to sample the model 100000 times, just call:

```
sample_100000 = model.getSample(100000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first question here is whether you have (1) time-series or (2) independent samples? If I understand your question I believe you are in the second scenario, in which you need to:

1. Look for a model that fits your frequency distribution:

I would suggest you start trying different main distributions (looking at your data exponential might be a good starting point). Here you can find a number of continuous distributions in SciPy :

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#continuous-distributions

If you want to automatically find the distribution with the least SSE for your data look at the answer from tmthydvnprt here:

[Fitting empirical distribution to theoretical ones with Scipy (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python)

2. Sample the model 100000 times

However, if it's time-series data you need to fit a time-series model instead of a frequency distribution. In this case, I suggest you start fitting an ARIMA model and move to more complex ones if this doesn't work: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html