# How to create Bayesian data fusion in python?

Tags: python, distribution, bayesian, pymc3, sensor-fusion

I have been looking into data fusion methods and what caught my eyes is the idea of using Kalman filter which looks into data fusion data which looks into mean and variance of Gaussian distribution and implements the prediction and correction from weak sensor to stronger/more accurate sensor. I looked into the following GitHub links to get a further understanding of fusion techniques:

1. [Kalman and Bayesian Filters in Python](https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python)
2. [Kalman Filter in 1 Dimension](https://github.com/balzer82/PyData-Berlin-2014-Kalman/blob/master/Kalman-Filter-1D.ipynb)

So, in the first link, I found they were talking about the discrete Bayesian filter, but, they didn’t mention about the continuous Bayesian filter. So, I thought to do the same steps with the idea from Kalman filter to implement a continuous Bayesian filter with the help of PyMC3 package. The steps involved can be found in the second link and code is below.

```
mean = mean0
var = var0

def predict(var, mean, varMove, meanMove):
    new_var = var + varMove
    new_mean= mean+ meanMove
    return new_var, new_mean

def correct(var, mean, varSensor, meanSensor):
    new_mean=(varSensor*mean + var*meanSensor) / (var+varSensor)
    new_var = 1/(1/var +1/varSensor)
    return new_var, new_mean

# Predict
var, mean = predict(var, mean, varMove, distances[m])
#print('mean: %.2f\tvar:%.2f' % (mean, var))
plt.plot(x,mlab.normpdf(x, mean, var), label='%i. step (Prediction)' % (m+1))
        
# Correct
var, mean = correct(var, mean, varSensor, positions[m])
print('After correction:  mean= %.2f\tvar= %.2f' % (mean, var))
plt.plot(x,mlab.normpdf(x, mean, var), label='%i. step (Correction)' % (m+1))
```

So, from the data that I am using, I implemented the following link,

[Fitting empirical distribution to theoretical ones with Scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python)

from the link above and distribution list, Student T distribution fits with my data. To implement the data fusion idea is to be able to get the initial data and then use the parameters from the first model and implement them into the prediction models and collect parameters from prediction model to correction model. Here is my approach to the fusion (I apologise for lengthy code),

```
def S2_0_Bayesian_Interface(data):
########################################################################################################################
    with pm.Model() as model_0:
            # Prior Distributions for unknown model parameters:
            nu_0 = pm.HalfNormal('nu_0', sigma=10)
            sigma_0 = pm.HalfNormal('sigma_0', sigma=10)
            mu_0 = pm.Normal('mu_0', mu=0, sigma=10)

            # Observed data is from a Likelihood distributions (Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations):
            observed_data_0 = pm.StudentT('observed_data_0', nu=nu_0, mu=mu_0, sigma=sigma_0, observed=data)
    
            # draw 5000 posterior samples
            trace_0 = pm.sample(draws=5000, tune=3000, chains=2, cores=1)
    
            # Obtaining Posterior Predictive Sampling:
            post_pred_0 = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace_0, samples=3000)
            print(post_pred_0['observed_data_0'].shape)
            print('\nSummary: ')
            print(pm.stats.summary(data=trace_0))
            print(pm.stats.summary(data=post_pred_0))
########################################################################################################################
    return trace_0, post_pred_0

def S2_P_Bayesian_Interface(nu, mu, sigma, data):
########################################################################################################################
    with pm.Model() as model_P:
            # Prior Distributions for unknown model parameters:
            nu_P = pm.HalfNormal('nu_P', sigma=sigma)
            sigma_P = pm.HalfNormal('sigma_P', sigma=sigma)
            mu_P = pm.Normal('mu_P', mu=mu, sigma=sigma)

            # Observed data is from a Likelihood distributions (Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations):
            observed_data_P = pm.StudentT('observed_data_P', nu=nu_P, mu=mu_P, sigma=sigma_P, observed=data)
    
            # draw 5000 posterior samples
            trace_P = pm.sample(draws=5000, tune=3000, chains=2, cores=1)
    
            # Obtaining Posterior Predictive Sampling:
            post_pred_P = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace_P, samples=3000)
            print(post_pred_P['observed_data_P'].shape)
            print('\nSummary: ')
            print(pm.stats.summary(data=trace_P))
            print(pm.stats.summary(data=post_pred_P))
########################################################################################################################
    return trace_P, post_pred_P

def S1_C_Bayesian_Interface(nu, mu, sigma, data):
########################################################################################################################
    with pm.Model() as model_C:
            # Prior Distributions for unknown model parameters:
            nu_C = pm.HalfNormal('nu_C', sigma=sigma)
            sigma_C = pm.HalfNormal('sigma_C', sigma=sigma)
            mu_C = pm.Normal('mu_C', mu=mu, sigma=sigma)

            # Observed data is from a Likelihood distributions (Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations):
            observed_data_C = pm.StudentT('observed_data_C', nu=nu_C, mu=mu_C, sigma=sigma_C, observed=data)
    
            # draw 5000 posterior samples
            trace_C = pm.sample(draws=5000, tune=3000, chains=2, cores=1)
    
            # Obtaining Posterior Predictive Sampling:
            post_pred_C = pm.sample_posterior_predictive(trace_C, samples=3000)
            print(post_pred_C['observed_data_C'].shape)
            print('\nSummary: ')
            print(pm.stats.summary(data=trace_C))
            print(pm.stats.summary(data=post_pred_C))
########################################################################################################################
    return trace_C, post_pred_C

for m in range(len(S2_data_list)):
    print('\n')
    print('Acessing list number: ', m)
    # print(S2_data_list)
    # print(len(S2_data_list))
    # Initializing the PDF Distribution:
    print('#######################################################################################################')
    print('Designing the Bayesian PDF for initial Sensor 2:')
    trace_S2_0, post_pred_S2_0 = S2_0_Bayesian_Interface(data=S2_data_list[0])
    best_dist = getattr(st, 't')
    param_S2_0 = [np.mean(trace_S2_0['nu_0']), np.mean(trace_S2_0['mu_0']), np.mean(trace_S2_0['sigma_0'])]
    print('Parameters values = ', param_S2_0)
    pdf_S2_0, B_x_axis_pdf_S2_0, y_axis_pdf_S2_0 = make_pdf(data=S2_data_list[0], dist=best_dist, params=param_S2_0, size=len(trace_S2_0))
    print('#######################################################################################################')
    plt.plot(B_x_axis_pdf_S2_0, y_axis_pdf_S2_0, label='%i. step (Initial[S2])' % (m + 1))

    # Predict:
    print('#######################################################################################################')
    print('Designing the Bayesian PDF for predictive Sensor 2:')
    trace_S2_P, post_pred_S2_P = S2_P_Bayesian_Interface(nu=np.mean(trace_S2_0['nu_0']), mu=np.mean(trace_S2_0['mu_0']), sigma=np.mean(trace_S2_0['sigma_0']), data=S2_data_list[m])
    best_dist = getattr(st, 't')
    param_S2_P = [np.mean(trace_S2_P['nu_P']), np.mean(trace_S2_P['mu_P']), np.mean(trace_S2_P['sigma_P'])]
    print('Parameters values = ', param_S2_P)
    pdf_S2_P, B_x_axis_pdf_S2_P, y_axis_pdf_S2_P = make_pdf(data=S2_data_list[m], dist=best_dist, params=param_S2_P, size=len(trace_S2_P))
    print('#######################################################################################################')
    plt.plot(B_x_axis_pdf_S2_P, y_axis_pdf_S2_P, label='%i. step (Prediction[S2])' % (m + 1))

    # Correct:
    print('#######################################################################################################')
    print('Designing the Bayesian PDF for correction Sensor 1:')
    trace_S1_C, post_pred_S1_C = S1_C_Bayesian_Interface(nu=np.mean(trace_S2_P['nu_P']), mu=np.mean(trace_S2_P['mu_P']), sigma=np.mean(trace_S2_P['sigma_P']), data=S1_data_list[m])
    best_dist = getattr(st, 't')
    param_S1_C = [np.mean(trace_S1_C['nu_C']), np.mean(trace_S1_C['mu_C']), np.mean(trace_S1_C['sigma_C'])]
    print('Parameters values = ', param_S1_C)
    pdf_S1_C, B_x_axis_pdf_S1_C, y_axis_pdf_S1_C = make_pdf(data=S1_data_list[m], dist=best_dist, params=param_S1_C, size=len(trace_S1_C))
    print('#######################################################################################################')
    plt.plot(B_x_axis_pdf_S1_C, y_axis_pdf_S1_C, label='%i. step (Correction[S1])' % (m + 1))
    corr_pdf_S1 = y_axis_pdf_S1_C
    corr_pdf_S1_list.append(corr_pdf_S1)
    print('Corrected PDF: ', corr_pdf_S1)
    print('Length of Corrected PDF list = ', len(corr_pdf_S1_list))
    x_corr_pdf_list.append(B_x_axis_pdf_S1_C)
```

However, I am not sure if I am doing the steps correctly. Am I approaching the idea correctly? If not, how can I modify the code? Also, if possible share a tutorial explains the idea of multiplying two distributions and get scale and loc of the combined probability distribution?

***Edit 1:***

I was talking to someone about this concept and he mentioned doing Bayesian updating. How can I implement this way into my code and using PYMC3 package?