# Plot distribution data over bar plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a big dictionary containing frequencies, like this:

```
frequency = {3: 231, 6: 373, 8: 455}
```

where the dictionary keys represent the lengths of the sentences and the values the number of sentences with that length.

I created the bar plot like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(list(frequency.keys()), frequency.values(), log=True, color='g', width=0.5)
ax.set_title('DISTRIBUTION OF SENTENCE LENGTH')
ax.set_xlabel('Sentence length')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

the result is correct and is the following:

[image]

now what I would like to do is to draw the distribution of these values. Something like that:

[image]

How can I do? I have already tried to follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python?lq=1) (and others like this), but with poor results.
Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify - Do you want to draw the distribution AND the bar chart, or do you want to replace the bar chart with the distribution?

Comment: Both, the bar chart AND distribution. The bar chart I managed to do, I just need to add the distribution (the one I tried to draw to understand) to the bar chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In seaborn's `histplot` there is a `weights` parameter. It also allows to add a `kde`. The default bandwidth seems a bit too wide, it can be adjusted via `kde_kws={'bw_adjust': 0.3}`. With `discrete=True`, the histogram bins are adapted to the discrete values.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

frequencies = {1: 2000}
for i in range(2, 10):
    frequencies[i] = int(frequencies[i - 1] * np.random.uniform(1.02, 1.1))
for i in range(10, 500):
    frequencies[i] = int(frequencies[i - 1] * np.random.uniform(0.97, 0.99))
    if frequencies[i] == 0:
        break

ax = sns.histplot(x=frequencies.keys(), weights=frequencies.values(), discrete=True,
                  kde=True, kde_kws={'bw_adjust': 0.2}, line_kws={'linewidth': 3})
ax.margins(x=0.01)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]