# How can I create a continuous distribution of a dataset?

Tags: python, data-analysis, distribution

I wish to create a continuous probability distribution  from this dataset.

The 'Value' shows a measured value and the 'Weight' is the probability of measuring this value in this measurement.

I already graphed the data. [On the x-axis it shows the value, and the Y-axis the probability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ7mS.png). But I wish to create an exact distribution to fit this data.

In my data-analysis I eventually wish to compare several data distributions by their parameters. I hope you guys can help me out.

| Line # | Value | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.0538502 | 0.016508 |
| 1 | 0.0184823 | 0.0298487 |
| 2 | 0.0647929 | 0.0122637 |
| 3 | 0.0262852 | 0.0234716 |
| 4 | 0.0447611 | 0.0197072 |
| 5 | 0.0643164 | 0.0165399 |
| 6 | 0.0709176 | 0.0143751 |
| 7 | 0.0871276 | 0.012253 |
| 8 | 0.0341064 | 0.0197392 |
| 9 | 0.0593696 | 0.0143858 |
| 10 | 0.0436119 | 0.0202617 |
| 11 | 0.0505131 | 0.0191846 |
| 12 | 0.0378706 | 0.0207842 |
| 13 | 0.0298233 | 0.0250712 |
| 14 | 0.157727 | 0.0111866 |
| 15 | 0.0556603 | 0.0186408 |
| 16 | 0.0542849 | 0.017617 |
| 17 | 0.0395772 | 0.0180969 |
| 18 | 0.0694962 | 0.0117305 |
| 19 | 0.0343318 | 0.0229277 |
| 20 | 0.139291 | 0.00907511 |
| 22 | 0.0232517 | 0.0186514 |
| 23 | 0.207768 | 0.0069423 |
| 24 | 0.0156452 | 0.021872 |
| 25 | 0.117749 | 0.0100989 |
| 26 | 0.124017 | 0.0111973 |
| 27 | 0.0679313 | 0.0133407 |
| 28 | 0.0733413 | 0.0117198 |
| 29 | 0.100553 | 0.0133407 |
| 30 | 0.0695865 | 0.016508 |
| 31 | 0.117732 | 0.0138633 |
| 32 | 0.0540577 | 0.0170518 |
| 33 | 0.0736274 | 0.0170625 |
| 34 | 0.0332381 | 0.0293155 |
| 35 | 0.0803423 | 0.0159961 |
| 36 | 0.0465 | 0.0191846 |
| 37 | 0.0889299 | 0.0159854 |
| 38 | 0.053232 | 0.020251 |
| 39 | 0.131361 | 0.0122637 |
| 40 | 0.0233194 | 0.0240048 |
| 41 | 0.830735 | 0.0053107 |
| 42 | 0.341012 | 0.0069423 |
| 43 | 0.101263 | 0.0106534 |
| 44 | 0.127061 | 0.00959765 |
| 45 | 0.13706 | 0.0122637 |
| 46 | 0.120035 | 0.0106641 |
| 47 | 0.0801194 | 0.0138526 |
| 48 | 0.0617996 | 0.0165186 |
| 49 | 0.197555 | 0.0117305 |
| 50 | 0.0810635 | 0.0133301 |
| 51 | 0.0178539 | 0.0335811 |
| 52 | 0.0391433 | 0.0170518 |
| 53 | 0.0663863 | 0.0133194 |
| 54 | 0.0617675 | 0.0170625 |
| 55 | 0.00684359 | 0.0346582 |
| 56 | 0.0642299 | 0.0133301 |
| 57 | 0.00970105 | 0.0239941 |
| 58 | 0.0307687 | 0.0213068 |
| 59 | 0.0160796 | 0.0255937 |
| 60 | 0.0147901 | 0.0266388 |
| 61 | 0.073745 | 0.0122637 |
| 62 | 0.0420728 | 0.0207949 |
| 63 | 0.0211625 | 0.0207949 |
| 66 | 0.0241562 | 0.0255937 |
| 67 | 0.0329688 | 0.0239834 |
| 68 | 0.0739628 | 0.0181289 |
| 69 | 0.0149927 | 0.0266388 |
| 70 | 0.0130271 | 0.0378467 |
| 73 | 0.0107957 | 0.0351914 |
| 74 | 0.040447 | 0.0175744 |
| 75 | 0.00123215 | 0.0559756 |
| 76 | 0.0134575 | 0.0309151 |
| 77 | 0.00592594 | 0.0453116 |

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you mean by "creating a distribution"?

Comment: I do not yet know specifically what distribution will best fit the data. Do you if there is a way to test this? I'm not very known with working with distributions.

Comment: You should link to other SO questions you looked up first and explain why they didn't answer your question (i.e. why your question is unique).

Comment: Please don't paste images of code or data, and please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What are "slope of the segment" and "probability of slope value" referring to? How where they calculated?

Comment: @ThatNewGuy Are you actually advocating that OP link to all negative search results with explanations as to the lack of relevance?  They certainly should do due diligence searching for solutions, but what you seem to be asking isn't really feasible, nor is it a requirement for SO.

Comment: What are the weights, and how have they been determined?  Are they estimates of the density?  They can't be probabilities, since you've stated this is data from a continuous distribution.

Comment: I changed the explanation of the problem. Hopefully its more clear now.

Comment: What you're calling the 'probability weight' can not be a probability if this is a continuous distribution since P{X = x} = 0 for all x for continuous distributions, so I still don't know what that column means.  How was it constructed?

Comment: @pjs The "values" are related to the state of an enzym. I calculated the weights by dividing the time in the corresponding state by the total time (sum of the corresponding times). Yes, it are estimates of the densities.

Comment: So i basically want to translate this dataset to a probability distribution.

Comment: Are you asking for a curve fit here?  Are you looking for a polynomial that fits your data?

Comment: No, rather not, I think it might would work if I then normalize it. But it is necessary that I'am able to compare this distribution to other distributions. I think the best way to do this is by knowing the distribution and then comparing the parameters

Comment: @pjs not all, just one or two would be fine. The original question was very vague and could easily have been interpreted as a duplicate. The point is to give context for the question.

Comment: @yungdurum I hate to sound like a pest, but the weights are ***not*** probabilities because they sum up to ~1.391.  This would also seem to contradict your comment where you said they were derived by dividing the time-in-state by the total time.

Comment: @pjs Thanks! :), you actually identified  an error in my code. .

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the data you have is a sort of (non-normalized) histogram.

The first task is of course to plot it:

```py
df = df.sort_values('Value')
plt.plot(df['Value'], df['Weight'])
plt.xlabel('value')
plt.ylabel('weight')
```

[image]

At first glance, it could indicate an exponential or a power-law distribution, but let's see.

Let's first try to smooth out that curve:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm

x, w = df['Value'].values, df['Weight'].values
s = pd.DataFrame(sm.nonparametric.lowess(w, x, frac=0.2), columns=['x', 'w']).set_index('x').squeeze()
s = s.reindex(np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 200), method='ffill', limit=1).interpolate()
s.plot()
plt.plot(x, w, '.')
```

That gives an okay-ish fit:

[image]

We can then use that to generate a fake, crude "sample" following that smooth pdf:

```py
sample = np.random.choice(s.index, p=s/s.sum(), size=1000)
```

At that point, you can make QQ plots with various distributions following your intuition, and select one that seems to fit well:

```py
from scipy.stats import _continuous_distns as distns

# trying a normal (the default)
sm.qqplot(sample, line='q')
plt.title('Normal')
```

Clearly not a good fit at all (but we knew that from a first glance at the data):

[image]

```py
# trying an exponential
sm.qqplot(sample, distns.expon, line='q')
plt.title('Exponential')
```

Not very good either:

[image]

Perhaps a power-law would fit better?

```py
# we are only interested in the parameter a, so we are
# not going to let loc and scale be fitted;
# instead, we will freeze them at loc=0, scale=1
a, loc, size = distns.powerlaw.fit(sample, floc=0, fscale=1)

# then, we do the QQ plot with the fitted parameter a
sm.qqplot(sample, distns.powerlaw, distargs=(a,), line='q')
plt.title(f'Power law with a={a}')
```

[image]

**Corresponding distribution and how to use it**

You can now instantiate a distribution following what was found (type and parameters), draw random variates from it, and also plot the pdf directly for comparison purposes with the original data:

```py
g = distns.powerlaw(a=a)

# new points drawn according to g
v = g.rvs(size=100000)
plt.hist(v, bins=100, density=True, histtype='step');
```

[image]

Direct pdf plot and comparison with the original data:

```py
y = g.pdf(x)
plt.plot(x, y/y.sum())
plt.plot(x, w/w.sum(), '.')
plt.title('Normalized pdf and original sample data')
```

[image]

**Last word**

So, where to go from here?  You should look in depth into that distribution and its physical meaning, and see if that makes sense in the context of your experimental setup.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. 
This is my first project with working with distributions in Python, so maybe it sounds stupid.
But I was thinking I could also interpret the weight as the frequency of measuring that 'value' (it is actually based on it)'. What if I can create a histogram based on those frequencies? And then try to fit a distributions to it? Does this make sense? I also found this other 'solution'  of finding the best distribution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python?lq=1