# Why pdf values are Nan with hypsecant distribution?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution

I looked into the question [Best fit Distribution plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python) and I found that best fit distribution for my dataset is hypsecant distribution. When I ran the code with one part of my dataset, I got the parameters for loc and scale to be:

```
loc=0.040593036736931196 ; scale=-0.008338984851829193
```

however, when I input for instance this data into `hysecant.pdf` with `loc` and `scale`, I get Nans as a result instead of values. Why is that?

Here is my input:

```
[ 1.          0.99745057  0.93944708  0.83424019  0.78561204  0.63211263
  0.62151259  0.57883015  0.57512492  0.43878694  0.43813347  0.37548233
  0.33836774  0.29610761  0.32102182  0.31378472  0.24809515  0.24638145
  0.22580595  0.18480387  0.19404362  0.18919147  0.16377272  0.16954728
  0.10912106  0.12407758  0.12819846  0.11673824  0.08957689  0.10353764
  0.09469576  0.08336001  0.08591166  0.06309568  0.07445366  0.07062173
  0.05535625  0.05682546  0.06803674  0.05217558  0.0492794   0.05403819
  0.04535857  0.04562529  0.04259798  0.03830373  0.0374102   0.03217575
  0.03291147  0.0288506   0.0268235   0.02467415  0.02409625  0.02486308
 -0.02563436 -0.02801487 -0.02937738 -0.02948851 -0.03272476 -0.03324265
 -0.03435844 -0.0383104  -0.03864602 -0.04091095 -0.04269355 -0.04428056
 -0.05009069 -0.05037519 -0.05122204 -0.05770342 -0.06348465 -0.06468936
 -0.06849683 -0.07477151 -0.08893675 -0.097383   -0.1033376  -0.10796748
 -0.11835636 -0.13741154 -0.14920072 -0.16698451 -0.1715277  -0.20449029
 -0.22241856 -0.25270058 -0.25699927 -0.26731036 -0.31098857 -0.35426224
 -0.36204168 -0.44059844 -0.46754863 -0.53560093 -0.61463112 -0.65583547
 -0.66378605 -0.70644849 -0.75217157 -0.92236344]
```

Comment: The scale of a SciPy distribution should never be negative.  Something went wrong with your fitting procedure.

Comment: *"Here is my input: ..."*  If I give that data to `hypsecant.fit`, I get `loc=0.01811167513521013` and `scale=0.19804277629175343`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I am working with pymc3 which a Bayesian probabilistic package and I created a custom distribution that is supposed to be Hypsecant distribution. Here is the link to the question, (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68231791/how-to-create-hypsecant-distribution-and-what-priors-to-use-with-the-distributio) I got the loc and scale by using the following code `param = [np.mean(trace['mu']), np.mean(trace['sigma'])]`, this is how I got the negative value. If you have experience with pymc3, could you have a look and see if I created Hypsecant distribution which is same as SciPy?

Comment: I've only used pymc3 at the level of "Hello, world", so I don't think I can help you with that (e.g. I don't know what your `trace` variable is).