# Fitting distribution to data (scipy/fitter/etc.)

Tags: python, scipy, distribution

I have the following data:

```py
y = np.array([8.8,7.2,5.8,4.7,3.8,3.1,2.6,2.2,2.0,1.7,1.8,1.8,1.9,1.7,1.4,1.2,1.7,1.2,1.5])   
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19])
```

I wish to fit a distribution to this data.

I've tried using scipy and fitter, but the distributions were of poor fit.

[I got results akin to this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70777070/not-normalized-data-with-fitter-in-python)

1. Why do the distributions in said example seem to be scaled below the true data?
2. Using my data, how do I fit a reasonable distribution? Any worked examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you get this data?  What is it?  It is not random samples from a univariate distribution, because you have `x` and `y`.  (Or are the `x` values just sample numbers?)  It is not samples from a PDF, because the integral over the whole x interval would be much larger than 1.  It is not samples from a CDF (or even from a scaled CDF), because the y values decrease.

Comment: Good points.    
(1) How did I get this data: It was gathered via a biological experiment.

Comment: (2) What is it? The x data represents a particular events, specifically, the number of 'breaks' at a certain site in the genome. For a given site where x = 6, that site would have 6 recorded 'breaks'. The y data represents the number of times we see each x value. For y=4 and x = 6, we'd see 4 different sites where the genome broke 6 times.

Comment: (3) Is it univariate? It is univariate. Where y varies, x values are essentially sample numbers (if I understand correctly). If it helps, I wish to fit a distribution to the values of y e.g. exponential or f etc.

Comment: (4) Is it a CDF? It is not a CDF.

Comment: (5) Is it a PDF? Ah, I see the issue. I want a PDF, however, your observation regarding the integral is sound - this is a unclear/wrong on my part. I will try to clarify my goals:

Comment: I have y data (essentially count data - they're not integers because I scaled them down from larger values) for the first 19 'x' values.   
In reality, the distribution actually ends at a much greater x value (x_max) - let's say x_max=100.  
I want to use the y data I have (for x values 1 to 19) to create a distribution which spans all the way to 100 (x_max).
- Using this distribution, I could then pick a new x value (let's say at x = 80) and get the corresponding y probability.

Comment: Given that I don't have data to represent the entire PDF, is it possible to create one? The issue I can currently see is that I won't know how to scale my existing data, such that the final integral of the PDF = 1.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  If I understand correctly, `x` is inherently discrete.  That is, it is nonsensical to have a value of `x` be, say, 23.45.  Is that correct?

Comment: You are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem via these steps:

(1) Warren's answer outlined that I couldn't fit a PDF - the 'area under the curve' was far greater than 1, and it should equal 1.

(2) Instead, I fit a curve to my data via the following code:

```
# Create a function which can create your line of best fit. In my case it's a 5PL equation. 
def func_5PL(x, d, a, c, b, g):
    return d + ((a-d)/((1+((x/c)**b))**g))

# Determine the coefficients for your equation.
popt_mock, _ = curve_fit(func_5PL, x, y)

# Plot the real data, along with the line of best fit. 
plt.plot(x, func_5PL(x, *popt_mock), label='line of best fit')
plt.scatter(x, y, label='real data')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
```

[my data, when a curve it fit to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzIeY.png)

(4) When I had the curve, I just rescaled it such that it's integral was equal to 1 (for the range of x values that I was interested in). I treated this as my pdf.